# Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream

Tags: c++, c, file, file-io, fstream

Is there a (cross-platform) way to get a C FILE* handle from a C++ std::fstream ?

The reason I ask is because my C++ library accepts fstreams and in one particular function I'd like to use a C library that accepts a FILE*.

Comment: Starting with C++ 2026, we have a [`native_handle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034062#answer-77676247) function (finally!)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The reason, is because the `std::fstream` is not required to use a `FILE*` as part of its implementation. So even if you manage to extract file descriptor from the `std::fstream` object and manually build a FILE object, then you will have other problems because you will now have two buffered objects writing to the same file descriptor.

The real question is why do you want to convert the `std::fstream` object into a `FILE*`?

Though I don't recommend it, you could try looking up `funopen()`.
Unfortunately, this is **not** a POSIX API (it's a BSD extension) so its portability is in question. Which is also probably why I can't find anybody that has wrapped a `std::stream` with an object like this.

```
FILE *funopen(
              const void *cookie,
              int    (*readfn )(void *, char *, int),
              int    (*writefn)(void *, const char *, int),
              fpos_t (*seekfn) (void *, fpos_t, int),
              int    (*closefn)(void *)
             );
```

This allows you to build a `FILE` object and specify some functions that will be used to do the actual work. If you write appropriate functions you can get them to read from the `std::fstream` object that actually has the file open.

Comment: Too bad it's only for BSD; it would have been a great solution since it would allow to use a FILE* with any kind of C++ stream.

Comment: You asked "why?": because one may have a C implementation of print written in C that one may what to reuse for C++ ostreams (or ofstreams).

Comment: Why? Because overloading the operator<< is very convenient when I'm *using* an object, but formatting stream output can be messy and painful. Formatting with fprintf() is compact and easy. In other words, I would like to be able to write `out << someObject << anotherObject` but implement operator<< using `fprintf(ofp, "%8.1lf  %2d\n", doubleVar, intVar)`

Comment: If you want/need to use the "printf" formatting paradigm, you could always use sprintf to create a c-string and then send that to your ofstream.   Of course, this means  you need to have a sense of the upper bound on your formatted string length so that you can size your char[] correctly.

Comment: @MikeMayer67 There are better ways to get sprinf formatting in streams. Boost had a stream format class a while back. Even I wrote a stream formatter object for fun a while back [C-String Formatter Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188812/c-string-formatter-again-part-4) See [Part 1 of the review for usage examples](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/188809/507)

Comment: @MartinYork.  Agreed, but not environments have Boost (not on the system I develop on... and it will not be added).  Writing your own formatter takes a little more time than simply using sprintf. It may not be the best solution (no argument here), but it is a very quick implementation where development speed is a driving design factor.

Comment: The GNU `fopencookie` function has the same functionality with a slightly different interface,

Answer (score 19):

There isn't a standardized way.  I assume this is because the C++ standardization group didn't want to assume that a file handle can be represented as a fd.

Most platforms do seem to provide some non-standard way to do this.

http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/ provides a good writeup of the situation and provides code that hides all the platform specific grossness, at least for GCC.  Given how gross this is just on GCC, I think I'd avoid doing this all together if possible.

Comment: A `FILE*` and file descriptor are *different* objects, and they are used by different components. One is used by the C runtime library, the other is used by the OS. See [What's the difference between a file descriptor and file pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2423628)

Answer (score 13):

> UPDATE: See @Jettatura what I think it is the best answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612982/225186 (Linux only?).

ORIGINAL:

(Probably not cross platform, but simple)

Simplifying the hack in [http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/](http://www.ginac.de/%7Ekreckel/fileno/) (dvorak answer), and looking at this gcc extension http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00069.html#a59f78806603c619eafcd4537c920f859,
I have this solution that works on `GCC` (4.8 at least) and `clang` (3.3 at least) before C++11:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<ext/stdio_filebuf.h>

typedef std::basic_ofstream<char>::__filebuf_type buffer_t;
typedef __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char>            io_buffer_t; 
FILE* cfile_impl(buffer_t* const fb){
    return (static_cast<io_buffer_t* const>(fb))->file(); //type std::__c_file
}

FILE* cfile(std::ofstream const& ofs){return cfile_impl(ofs.rdbuf());}
FILE* cfile(std::ifstream const& ifs){return cfile_impl(ifs.rdbuf());}
```

and can be used this,

```
int main(){
    std::ofstream ofs("file.txt");
    fprintf(cfile(ofs), "sample1");
    fflush(cfile(ofs)); // ofs << std::flush; doesn't help 
    ofs << "sample2\n";
}
```

**Note:** The `stdio_filebuf` is not used in newer versions of the library. The `static_cast<>()` is somewhat dangerous too. Use a `dynamic_cast<>()` instead of if you get a `nullptr` you need that's not the right class. You can try with `stdio_sync_filebuf` instead. Problem with that class is that the `file()` is not available at all anymore.

**Limitations:** (comments are welcome)

1. I find that it is important to `fflush` after `fprintf` printing to `std::ofstream`, otherwise the "sample2" appears before "sample1" in the example above. I don't know if there is a better workaround for that than using `fflush`. Notably `ofs << flush` doesn't help.
2. Cannot extract FILE* from `std::stringstream`, I don't even know if it is possible. (see below for an update).
3. I still don't know how to extract C's `stderr` from `std::cerr` etc., for example to use in `fprintf(stderr, "sample")`, in an hypothetical code like this `fprintf(cfile(std::cerr), "sample")`.

Regarding the last limitation, the only workaround I found is to add these overloads:

```
FILE* cfile(std::ostream const& os){
    if(std::ofstream const* ofsP = dynamic_cast<std::ofstream const*>(&os)) return cfile(*ofsP);
    if(&os == &std::cerr) return stderr;
    if(&os == &std::cout) return stdout;
    if(&os == &std::clog) return stderr;
    if(dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream const*>(&os) != 0){
       throw std::runtime_error("don't know cannot extract FILE pointer from std::ostringstream");
    }
    return 0; // stream not recognized
}
FILE* cfile(std::istream const& is){
    if(std::ifstream const* ifsP = dynamic_cast<std::ifstream const*>(&is)) return cfile(*ifsP);
    if(&is == &std::cin) return stdin;
    if(dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream const*>(&is) != 0){
        throw std::runtime_error("don't know how to extract FILE pointer from std::istringstream");
    }
    return 0; // stream not recognized
}
```

**Attempt to handle `iostringstream`**

It is possible to read with `fscanf` from `istream` using `fmemopen`, but that requires a lot of book keeping and updating the input position of the stream after each read, if one wants to combine C-reads and C++-reads. I wasn't able to convert this into a `cfile` function like above. (Maybe a `cfile` *class* that keeps updating after each read is the way to go).

```
// hack to access the protected member of istreambuf that know the current position
char* access_gptr(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>& bs){
    struct access_class : std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>{
        char* access_gptr() const{return this->gptr();}
    };
    return ((access_class*)(&bs))->access_gptr();
}

int main(){
    std::istringstream iss("11 22 33");
    // read the C++ way
    int j1; iss >> j1;
    std::cout << j1 << std::endl;

    // read the C way
    float j2;
   
    char* buf = access_gptr(*iss.rdbuf()); // get current position
    size_t buf_size = iss.rdbuf()->in_avail(); // get remaining characters
    FILE* file = fmemopen(buf, buf_size, "r"); // open buffer memory as FILE*
    fscanf(file, "%f", &j2); // finally!
    iss.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(ftell(file), iss.cur, iss.in); // update input stream position from current FILE position.

    std::cout << "j2 = " << j2 << std::endl;

    // read again the C++ way
    int j3; iss >> j3;
    std::cout << "j3 = " << j3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is great! I recently had to do some tcsetattr() work on something that came in as an ofstream and your writeup really helped me out.

Comment: Thank you.  I used this approach for file locking, as summarized here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689083/5899976

Comment: @DroidCoder, interesting that there is no mechanism to replace flock in fstreams. I wonder if that is because it is not a very portable (across filesystem) feature in the first place.

Comment: Agreed.  Reading the documentation of Boost.Interprocess, it seems there are a number of platform-specific behaviors that would make it annoying to standardize.  Still, its absence leaves a pretty large hole, so I feel it's worth the effort to try and get the platform folks to support a common subset of behaviors that can lay the groundwork for support in a future C++ standard.

Comment: This should perhaps be the accepted answer. I have referenced it in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream which was motivated by performance gain of using `std::fread` vs `std::ifstream::read`.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock , this question was asked by an unregistered user (Bek?) back in 2008, I doubt he is still around or can recover the account to accept the answer. I don't know if admins can accept answers.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock, did you try this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612982/225186 ? When I checked it seemed to be superior. I don't remember the details.

Comment: I didn't. Bit too much code for my case, and still only for linux, I liked yours better. Especially since I need seek as well, which it looks like is lacking in that implementation? BTW I pasted the wrong link above. This was my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435310/how-to-get-file-from-a-stdifstream-in-order-to-call-stdfread

Comment: Note that for `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, and `clog`, you should use `typedef __gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<char> io_sync_buffer_t;`. You can `dynamic_cast<io_sync_buffer_t const *>(blah.rdbud())` and if not `nullptr`, you can then use the `file()` function to retrieve the `FILE*` pointer. Much cleaner than using the `&os == &cout` and in that case switching to `stdout` which may or may not represent the current output buffer of the C++ streams (i.e. one can change the `rdbuf()` of any stream).

Comment: Okay, I see what happened. In C++98, it used the old `stdio_filebuf<>` class. In newer version (C++11 and newer) it uses `stdio_sync_filebuf<>` instead.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, ok, feel free add a note to my answer if you find a better way.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can get the file descriptor - I forget whether the method is fd() or getfd().  *The implementations I've used provide such methods, but the language standard doesn't require them, I believe - the standard shouldn't care whether your platform uses fd's for files.*

From that, you can use fdopen(fd, mode) to get a FILE*.

However, I think that the mechanisms the standard requires for synching STDIN/cin, STDOUT/cout and STDERR/cerr don't have to be visible to you.  So if you're using both the fstream and FILE*, buffering may mess you up.

Also, if either the fstream OR the FILE closes, they'll probably close the underlying fd, so you need to make sure you flush BOTH before closing EITHER.

Comment: Sorry, it's going to depend on which compiler/library you're using.

For libstdc++, it's fd(), it looks like: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_io.html

Answer (score 4):

yet another way to do this in Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassert>

template<class STREAM>
struct STDIOAdapter
{
    static FILE* yield(STREAM* stream)
    {
        assert(stream != NULL);

        static cookie_io_functions_t Cookies =
        {
            .read  = NULL,
            .write = cookieWrite,
            .seek  = NULL,
            .close = cookieClose
        };

        return fopencookie(stream, "w", Cookies);
    }

    ssize_t static cookieWrite(void* cookie,
        const char* buf,
        size_t size)
    {
        if(cookie == NULL)
            return -1;

        STREAM* writer = static_cast <STREAM*>(cookie);

        writer->write(buf, size);

        return size;
    }

    int static cookieClose(void* cookie)
    {
         return EOF;
    }
}; // STDIOAdapter
```

Usage, for example:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>

using namespace boost::iostreams;

int main()
{   
    filtering_ostream out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::bzip2_compressor());
    out.push(file_sink("my_file.txt"));

    FILE* fp = STDIOAdapter<filtering_ostream>::yield(&out);
    assert(fp > 0);

    fputs("Was up, Man", fp);

    fflush (fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I would complement it with `template<class Stream>
FILE* cfile(Stream& s){
 return STDIOAdapter<Stream>::yield(&s);
}`. It works with `std::cout`, `std::cerr` and mixing `fprintf` and C++ code. I would recommend using this.

Comment: I am commenting again to confirm that this works with `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: does it make sense to have `seek` function as well.  `int cookieSeek(void* cookie, ssize_t* off, int way){
  static_cast<std::iostream*>(cookie)->seekg(*off, static_cast<Stream*>(cookie)->end);
  return way;
 }` ?
 (I am not sure if I am using `way` correctly).

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. What's this business with cookies?

Comment: @Jettatura: So, it's non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

In a single-threaded POSIX application you can easily get the fd number in a portable way:

```
int fd = dup(0);
close(fd);
// POSIX requires the next opened file descriptor to be fd.
std::fstream file(...);
// now fd has been opened again and is owned by file
```

This method breaks in a multi-threaded application if this code races with other threads opening file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to get file descriptor from `fstream` and then convert it to `FILE*` (via `fdopen`). Personally I don't see any need in `FILE*`, but with file descriptor you may do many interesting things such as redirecting (`dup2`).

Solution:

```
#define private public
#define protected public
#include <fstream>
#undef private
#undef protected

std::ifstream file("some file");
auto fno = file._M_filebuf._M_file.fd();
```

The last string works for libstdc++. If you are using some other library you will need to reverse-engineer it a bit.

This trick is dirty and will expose all private and public members of fstream. If you would like to use it in your production code I suggest you to create separate `.cpp` and `.h` with single function `int getFdFromFstream(std::basic_ios<char>& fstr);`. Header file must not include fstream.

Comment: WUT? This is not only dirty but UB. Should definitely not be used.

Comment: @JHBonarius, if it's UB, nothing is going to work ever. Not even when you don't do that `#define` trick. C++ has always created the exact same structures whether everything is public or not.

Comment: @AlexisWilke well, that's not generally true. UB just means "behavior is not defined by the standard". In practice it "might" work. However, there are no guarantees. It might break from build to build or even run to run. So you shouldn't rely on UB. However, there also are some UB that have their behavior defined by compilers, and have been used for many years, for example because there was no other way. But it's not good practice and often you lock yourself in to a specific platform and compiler version. Avoid UB whenever possible.

Comment: @AlexisWilke in this case, `_M_filebuf` already is an libstdc++ specific internal implementation. As not defined in the C++ standard, they're free to modify or remove it from version to version. You have no guarantees and linking against another version of the library might break your code, or worse running against different binaries might cause bad things to happen.

Comment: Actually, there are already two implementations of the `stdio_filebuf` (C++98) and `stdio_sync_filebuf` (C++11 and newer). So we already have such. The old implementation gave you access to `file()`. The code above would not compile with the C++98 version. In regard to  incompatible binaries, I have that problem once in a while. I often recompile my whole project from scratch (902 C++ files so far) because it crashes... In most cases, this is because I changed a class and thus the layout of the fields changed between versions and I missed compiling/installing the modified library.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in that problem when I was faced with `isatty()` only working on a file descriptor.

In newer versions of the C++ standard library (at least since C++11), the solution proposed by alfC does not work anymore because that one class was changed to a new class.

The old method will still work if you use very old versions of the compiler. In newer version, you need to use `std::basic_filebuf<>()`. But that does not work with the standard I/O such as `std::cout`. For those, you need to use `__gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<>()`.

I have a functional example in my implementation of [`isatty()`](https://github.com/m2osw/snapdev/blob/main/snapdev/isatty.h) for C++ streams here. You should be able to lift off that one file and reuse it in your own project. In your case, though, you wanted the `FILE*` pointer, so just return that instead of the result of `::isatty(fileno(<of FILE*>))`.

Here is a copy of the template function:

```
template<typename _CharT
       , typename _Traits = std::char_traits<_CharT>>
bool isatty(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits> const & s)
{
    { // cin, cout, cerr, and clog
        typedef __gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits> io_sync_buffer_t;
        io_sync_buffer_t * buffer(dynamic_cast<io_sync_buffer_t *>(s.rdbuf()));
        if(buffer != nullptr)
        {
            return ::isatty(fileno(buffer->file()));
        }
    }

    { // modern versions
        typedef std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits> file_buffer_t;
        file_buffer_t * file_buffer(dynamic_cast<file_buffer_t *>(s.rdbuf()));
        if(file_buffer != nullptr)
        {
            typedef detail::our_basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits> hack_buffer_t;
            hack_buffer_t * buffer(static_cast<hack_buffer_t *>(file_buffer));
            if(buffer != nullptr)
            {
                return ::isatty(fileno(buffer->file()));
            }
        }
    }

    { // older versions
        typedef __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits> io_buffer_t;
        io_buffer_t * buffer(dynamic_cast<io_buffer_t *>(s.rdbuf()));
        if(buffer != nullptr)
        {
            return ::isatty(fileno(buffer->file()));
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, you should be asking: *But what is that detail class `our_basic_filebuf`*?!?

And that's a good question. The fact is that the `_M_file` pointer is protected and there is no `file()` (or `fd()`) in the `std::basic_filebuf`. For that reason, I created a *shell class* which has access to the protected fields and that way I can return the `FILE*` pointer.

```
template<typename _CharT
       , typename _Traits = std::char_traits<_CharT>>
class our_basic_filebuf
    : public std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>
{
public:
    std::__c_file * file() throw()
    {
        return this->_M_file.file();
    }
};
```

This is somewhat ugly, but cleanest I could think off to gain access to the `_M_file` field.

Answer (score 0):

[Revision of the idea of Alexis Wilke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932388/8444399)
It works for me under MSVC 2022 and MSYS2

```
namespace detail {

#ifdef _WIN32
using handle_type = HANDLE;
#else
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (-1)
using handle_type = int;
#endif

template <
    typename _Elem,
    typename _Traits = std::char_traits<_Elem>
>
class basic_filebuf_hack :
#ifdef _MSC_VER
public std::basic_streambuf<_Elem, _Traits> {
public:
    using _Cvt  = std::codecvt<_Elem, char, typename _Traits::state_type>;

    const _Cvt * _Pcvt;
    _Elem        _Mychar;
    bool         _Wrotesome;
    typename _Traits::state_type _State;
    bool         _Closef;
    FILE       * _Myfile;
    _Elem      * _Set_eback;
    _Elem      * _Set_egptr;
    
    __forceinline
    auto file() throw() {
        return this->_Myfile;
    }
#else
public std::basic_filebuf<_Elem, _Traits> {
    auto file() throw() {
        return this->_M_file.file();
    }
#endif
};
static_assert(sizeof(std::basic_filebuf<char>) == sizeof(basic_filebuf_hack<char>), "sizes not same");

} // namespace detail

template <
    typename _CharT,
    typename _Traits = std::char_traits<_CharT>
>
detail::handle_type ios_fileno(const std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits> & s) {
    using file_buffer_t = std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>;
    auto file_buffer = dynamic_cast<file_buffer_t *>(s.rdbuf());

    if (file_buffer != nullptr) {
        using hack_buffer_t = detail::basic_filebuf_hack<_CharT, _Traits>;
        auto buffer = reinterpret_cast<hack_buffer_t *>(file_buffer);

        if (buffer != nullptr) {
            auto file = buffer->file();

            if (file != nullptr) {
#ifdef _WIN32
                return detail::handle_type(_get_osfhandle(_fileno(file)));
#else
                return fileno(file);
#endif
            }
        }
    }

    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```