# How can I make a library that writes to FILE * write the data to memory instead? (C programming)

Tags: c, file, memory

I am facing a problem where the C library exposes only an interface that writes the data to a C `FILE` structure. This means all the data get saved to disk. I want this library to save the data to memory instead.

Is there a way to emulate `FILE` structure in my code and make it save the data in memory instead? I imagine `FILE` has various pointers to functions and I could write my own functions and make them allocate memory and on `fwrite` write the data to memory.

Can this be done?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539537/memory-buffer-as-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A portable solution would be to use `fmemopen` or `open_memstream` if these functions are available (they've been part of GNU libc for a long time and they were added to POSIX in 2008) and simply write to a temporary file then read back into memory if they're not.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at fmemopen.

Answer (score 1):

On a UNIX system, you can use `fdopen(3)` to get a `FILE*` that uses a stream you previously opened.  Then all you have to do is write some code to read from the other side of that pipe and shovel it into memory.

Comment: I like this solution, but it's not so easy. It will require either threads or forking and using shared memory.