# Creating a memory file

Tags: c++, file, winapi, memory, createfile

I want to create a temporary file in memory, **without it writing to disk**, that can be opened for reading using `CreateFile` from other processes as if it was a normal file.

Is this possible or do I have to write it to the disk?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135854/make-a-file-pointer-read-write-to-an-in-memory-location

Comment: @AmericanPatriot Since I am working with the Windows API, also known as WinAPI.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge `fmemopen` doesn't seem to be available on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, POSIX is like that.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge `fmemopen` returns `FILE*` mapped to the process memory space - you cannot share that across multiple processes. For sharing you need something accessible by path in FS - known to all.

Comment: Search the internet for "memory mapped file".  This is a platform specific topic, so you should include your platform name in the query.

Comment: You can certainly do it with a memory mapped file but there's always the possibility it will hit the disk if the memory system needs to swap it out.

Comment: Typical technology for sharing memory between processes is [Named Shared Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx). However you won't be able to use CreateFile to access it. If CreateFile is not a hard requirement, I would suggest looking into shared memory segment.

Comment: The question sounds a lot, like you are asking about your solution rather than your issue. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for cannot generally be done with `CreateFile()` (unless you go the RAMdisk approach), but it can be done using `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` instead.  The mapping object can be assigned a name so it can be shared across process boundaries, and then multiple processes can have their own views open to it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

CreateFile takes file path as a parameter. For other processes to be able to open it that file location shall be mapped to one of devices existing in the system.

One of such devices can be a RAM disk/device where you can create files without writing them to physical disk (memory swapping aside). But that requires installation and activation of such a (virtual) device.

If you just need to share memory between processes then take a look on [shmem implementation](http://garret.ru/shmem/Readme.htm) for example.

Comment: That link is useless. Shared memory on Windows is done using `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.