# C, perform file operations with array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I want to perform file operations(*fread, fwrite... etc*) with a array(*char*, but if is possible with any type also will be good*).

I know that i can do it with sprintf and sscanf, but i no want use these.
Why? i are writing a Intel 8080 emulator, and i are writing the RAM, so i will read more that individual chars, read ints and so on.

I want use fread and fwrite because you can give them the size of the elements, with sprintf and sscanf you can use format, but i must write code for every type.

At this moment i don't have any issues, nor much code, i only want know if my question has a answer, else i will see how convert a array of char to other data type...

Resuming, i can use char* as FILE* ?.

---

*Sorry for my bat English...*

Comment: For a 8080 emulator, I would just use a 64K file, and mmap() it.

Comment: Can you please provide some code, even pseudo-code, which demonstrates how you want to call the operations and give examples of input and desired output?

Comment: Just a well meant recommendation: if you ask such a question, I somehow doubt you are fit to write an CPU emulator. Start with a less challenging project, e.g. work through a good C book about modern C (not K&R, not C90 - learn C99, better standard C11). Any textbook will explain the file functions and all other facilities you need.

Comment: his question is not, how to write a char array to a file. His question is 'can I use a memory array as a file' A totally different question - take a look at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html

Comment: thats fmemopen. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135854/make-a-file-pointer-read-write-to-an-in-memory-location