# Can I replace a call to open_memstream with a malloc and an implicit cast?

Tags: c, windows, stream, malloc

All,

I have a program that prints to a stream. I need to buffer this stream in memory, and then print each line as necessary to an actual file later.

Since the `fprintf()` function calls must have a `FILE *` pointer, I need to have said pointer addressing space in memory. I had used the `open_memstream()` function, but this is not supported on windows.

Since `malloc()` returns a `void *` pointer that magically casts to the necessary pointer as needed, could I use that as my `FILE *` pointer? If so, what caveats are there? Do I need to watch out for running out of space?

**Update:**

After finding the source for `open_memstream()`, which was harder than it should have been, it looks like they are doing a file stream to malloc'd space.

Since that is the case, and I've got their source, I'm going to se if I can't get a working version to cross compile for windows with mingw.

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: [C - create file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12249610/995714), [How to map BYTE array as FILE * on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46836658/995714), [How to write to a memory buffer with a FILE*?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/539537/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who come after me, have hope! There is a solution. As noted in my question, I was using `open_memstream()`, which is unsupported on windows.

Since I have a `File *` pointer (this cannot be changed to `char *`), I needed to redirect it to memory until later. Since I'm dealing with a file in memory, I looked into `mmap()`. It handily solves the problem, but again, it is linux only.

But, windows includes a corollary to `mmap()` called `MapViewOfFile()`. Through the magic of `#ifdef` I've got it using whichever is necessary:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <sys/mman.h>
#endif
```

Later on, in the main method, I call `tmpfile()` which is supported on both platforms. This opens a stream to a guaranteed unique temporary file for me. Now that I have my `FILE *` pointer, I need to `mmap()` the space. But `mmap()` needs a file descriptor, not a stream, so I used the `fileno()` function to get the new file descriptor.

```
/* create tmp file and get file descriptor */
int fd;
yyout = tmpfile();
fd = fileno(yyout);
```

Now I have some more `#ifdef` code to determine which memory mapping codeset needs to be used. Note the difference in the mapped space between the two versions. Windows maps `16384 bytes` and linux maps `4096 bytes`. This is because the smaller value segfaults on windows, as noted in [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10339473/724357).

```
#ifdef WIN32
    HANDLE fm;
    HANDLE h = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle (fd);

    fm = CreateFileMapping(
             h,
             NULL,
             PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_RESERVE,
             0,
             16384,
             NULL);
    if (fm == NULL) { 
            fprintf (stderr, "%s: Couldn't access memory space! %s\n", argv[0],  strerror (GetLastError()));
            exit(GetLastError());
    }
    bp = (char*)MapViewOfFile(
              fm,
              FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
              0,
              0,
              0);
    if (bp == NULL) { 
            fprintf (stderr, "%s: Couldn't fill memory space! %s\n", argv[0],  strerror (GetLastError()));
            exit(GetLastError());
    }
#else
    bp = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (bp == MAP_FAILED) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s: Couldn't access memory space! %s\n", argv[0], FileName, strerror (errno));
            exit(errno);
    }
#endif
```

A bunch of work now happens, wherin data is sent to the `yyout` stream. Eventually the `flushData()` method gets called. It finalizes the stream with a null terminated character, flushes it, and then rewinds it. Then the pointer to the *memory space* is passed through a function pointer, along with the proper stream to print to.

```
void flushData(void) {
    /* write out data in the stream and reset */ 
    while (currFields < headerFields) { fprintf(yyout, ",\"\""); currFields++; } 
    currFields = 0;
    fprintf(yyout, "%c%c%c", 13, 10, '\0');
    fflush(yyout);
    rewind(yyout);
    if (faqLine == 1) {
        faqLine = 0; /* don't print faq's to the data file */
    }
    else {
        (*printString)(outfile, bp);
        fflush(outfile);
    }
    fflush(yyout);
    rewind(yyout);
}
```

This is one of the functions that could be pointed to for printing. It walks the memory space and prints each char until it hits the null printed earlier.

```
int printAnsi( FILE *outstream, char *string) {
    /* loop over the chars in string and print them to the outputstream as ansi */
    char * ps = string;
    while (*ps != '\0') {
        fprintf(outstream, "%c", *ps);
        ps++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The end result of all this being that I have a stream to memory space just like `open_memstream()`, up to also having a char pointer I can use to walk through the memory space if necessary. It is cross platform, and (seemingly) fully functional.

If anyone wants more details or have notes about problems I should fix, please add a comment.

Comment: Nice! While looking into this same problem I also came across this MIT-licensed library that looks to basically do the same solution, albeit it attempts to be cross platform and detect what the user environment has available https://github.com/Snaipe/fmem/blob/master/src/fmem-winapi-tmpfile.c

Comment: Do you call `UnmapViewOfFile` or any other cleanup function besides `fclose` when you're done?

Answer (score 2):

No. `malloc()` just gives you a block of (probably uninitialized) memory. There's no "magical" casting going on; when you do `int * buf = malloc(10*sizeof(int);` you are pointing `buf` at, effectively, 10 uninitialized ints.

The corresponding thing with a FILE would be `FILE * f = malloc(10*sizeof(FILE));` which points `f` at 10 uninitialized FILE structures, which doesn't make any sense. Furthermore, writing to an uninitialized FILE is likely to result in a crash if you're *lucky*.

It's easier to help if you tell us what platforms you're targeting and what you actually want to achieve. On POSIX, you can use `shm_open()` to get a file descriptor pointing to "shared memory" and `fdopen()` to turn the file descriptor to a `FILE*`. Yes, it might run out of space.