# How to convert a string into a Standard C File ?

Tags: c++

Hi I have an image in my memory and I want to sent it through an external FTP library.

This FTP library accepts only and only standard [C FILE](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) and the sample codes provided by this library reads data only from hard disk. In my application I don't want to store my images in the hard disk and then read them using FILE variable, instead I want to do the conversion in my memory so it's faster and more professional.

My image is in the form of `uchar *` but I can change it to `std::String` or `QByteArray` or any other type of string. Now I want to know how can I have a file which is filled by my image data so I will get rid of storing it into the hard disk and read it again.

My pseudo code:

```
   uchar * image = readImage();
   FILE * New_Image = String2FileConverter(image); //I need this function
   FTP_Upload(New_Image);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Posix systems, you can use [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) to create a memory-backed file handle.

Comment: Here's the analogous [question for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249610/c-create-file-in-memory).