# cast char* to FILE* without saving the file

Tags: c, file, encryption, fopen

im trying to open an existing file in "rb" mode and i need to decrypt returning a new FILE* without overwrite the original file or creating new temporary one.
in short words, i need something like this:

```
FILE *decrypt(){
    FILE *cryptedfile = fopen("file.ext", "rb");

    //... my decrypter code

    return (the decrypted file as FILE*).
}
```

so, there is a way to do something like "cast char* to FILE*"?

i have tried many different solutions without success, i have also tried to create a new tmpfile() but the result seems do not work properly and i do not want to create a tmpfile anyway, but just keep it into the memory.

**thanks** **:)**

Comment: The only way to get a valid `FILE *` is to use `fopen`.  Why don't you just return the decrypted contents in a byte array?

Comment: You already "converted" your `const char*` to a `FILE*` when you called `fopen`.

Comment: sure, my decrypter code will process the file content and return it as char*, but i need to convert it to FILE* again without saving it.

Comment: `return (the decrypted file as FILE*).` then you have to create a new file that is decrypted and write to it close it, then open it  again for reading. Seems like a weird requirement or at least an insecure one.

Comment: Why?  What purpose does it serve to have a `FILE *`?  What's wrong with getting a `char *` pointing to the decrypted data?

Comment: i need FILE* and not char* because im using a thirdparty code that require FILE* to do other processes. :(

Comment: i do not want to create a new temporary file since the encrypted data are precious :\

Comment: If you are on a POSIX compliant system you can use `fmemopen()`.

Comment: Cross platform: https://github.com/Snaipe/fmem

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24683052/3002139

Comment: Possible dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5135854/3002139 https://stackoverflow.com/q/539537/3002139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decrypting the data, you can create a pipe to feed the decrypted data into, then you can return the read end of the pipe to read the data.

```
FILE *decrypt(){
    FILE *cryptedfile = fopen("file.ext", "rb");

    char *data;
    int len;
    // load decrypted data into "data" and length info "len"

    int p[2];
    if (pipe(p) == -1) {
        perror("pipe failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    int rval;
    if ((rval = write(p[1], data, len)) == -1) {
        perror("write failed");
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        return NULL;
    } else if (rval < len) {
        printf("write failed, wrote %d, expected %d\n", rval, len);
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        return NULL;
    }

    return fdopen(p[0], "r");
}
```

Alternately, you can also use `fmemopen`:

```
FILE *decrypt(){
    FILE *cryptedfile = fopen("file.ext", "rb");

    char *data;
    int len;
    // load decrypted data into "data" and length info "len"

    return fmemopen(data, len, "rb");
}
```

Comment: What happens if the decrypted data is larger than the pipe's buffer?

Comment: @Shawn You'll get a write error if that happens.  Linux defaults to 64K, but that can be increased via `fcntl` using the `F_SETPIPE_SZ` option.

Comment: Thank you all for these answers in such a short time
@dbush i have tried your code, and it works but seems it works only if the char* doesnt contain spaces. if the data contains a space, the program keep alive without doing anything.

Comment: @Giuseppe glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer[(https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: sorry, not spaces but returns char like "\n"

Comment: I'll explain for example: if i set data = "helloworld" and len = 10 it works perfectly. but if data is = "hello world" and len = 11 the program keep alive doing nothing; but if len is = 5 (to the "o" of "hello") it works by writing only "hello" word. what's wrong?

Comment: i fixed by replacing pipe(p) with _pipe(p, len, O_BINARY)