# Run .exe and redirect stdin and out

Tags: c++, c++11, redirect

For most of my life, I've been using `cstdio`. Now I'm trying to shift over to `iostream`.

Suppose I have a separate program called "foo.cpp" that looks like this:

```
int main(){ // foo.cpp
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x + 5 << "\n";
}
```

In another program called "bar.cpp", I call the foo executable. In the past, if I wanted to redirect stdin and stdout to a file, I would use `freopen` like so:

```
int main(){ // bar.cpp, redirecting stdin and stdout
    freopen("foo.in", "r", stdin); // Suppose "foo.in" contains a single integer "42"
    freopen("foo.out", "w", stdout);

    system("foo.exe"); // "foo.out" will contain "47"
}
```

Now I'm trying to redirect `std::cin` and `std::cout` to stringstreams. Something like this:

```
int main(){ // bar.cpp, redirecting cin and cout
    std::istringstream instr("62");
    std::ostringstream outstr;

    std::cin.rdbuf(instr.rdbuf());
    std::cout.rdbuf(outstr.rdbuf());

    system("foo.exe"); // outstr should contain "67"
}
```

But what I've learned is that `std::cin` and `std::cout` was not redirected when executing "foo.exe". The program now expected user input and will print to `std::cout`. When execution of "foo.exe" was done, `std::cin` and `std::cout` within "bar.cpp" still remained redirected to `instr` and `outstr` respectively.

My question is, is there a way to do it with `iostream` like I intended, or am I stuck with using `freopen`?

Comment: The operating system is in charge of processing the output of executables.  The C++ language has no facilities for redirecting output.

Comment: Common solutions for sharing data between programs:  files, sockets, piping (tell OS to pipe output of other program into standard input for your program), shared memory areas.  Search the internet.

Comment: Have you tried just making the same freopen calls?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen a `freopen` call in a while. This brings back some old memories.

Anyway, I think you should stick with `freopen`. The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) page of the function literally states that this is one of the main use cases:

> This function is especially useful for redirecting predefined streams like *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* to specific files.

I don't think you can do the redirection with `iostream` only, because the `iostream` library doesn't have an equivalent for the `freopen` function.

It is interesting though why this solution you tried doesn't work:

```
std::cin.rdbuf(instr.rdbuf());
std::cout.rdbuf(outstr.rdbuf());
```

Maybe with those two lines you just affect the *rdbuf* of `std::cin` and `std::cout` from the current process and the subprocess has another instance of `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

The information about files seems to be copied from the parent process to the subprocess when calling `system`. That is why the changes you do in the main process on *stdin* and *stdout* with `freopen` are also visible in the subprocess.

Regardless, [you should not use system](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/) to run a subprogram from your main C++ program. As you are probably on Windows (guessing from `foo.exe`), I would analyze this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft. It explains how to create a subprocess and use pipes to redirect the input and output of the subprogram.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code using freopen, you are redirecting to/from physical files, correct? In your sample code using std::istringstream and std::ostringstream you are trying to redirect to/from memory, correct? Physical files are not the same as memory. Memory does not have file descriptors. In Linux you can use fmemopen as in [windows - C - create file in memory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249610/c-create-file-in-memory) but that won't help with C++ standard classes such as std::istringstream and std::ostringstream nor would you be able to redirect stdin and stdout to/from fmemopen, for one thing because fmemopen is not available in all operating systems. The C++ standard classes don't support this type of thing; see [c++ - Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream). std::istream and std::ostream might look like std::istringstream and std::ostringstream at the C++ interace level but internally they are not compatible.