# Use char array as a file stream

Tags: c, unix

How do I use a `char` array to be the data storage for a `FILE` stream?

```
char buffer[max_len];
FILE *fp = fopen(<I want to use data in buffer variable as file data>, "r");
```

The goal is to have data ready in `fp` for the following behavior:

```
execl("/bin/cat", "cat",  fp, (char *)NULL);
```

Additionally, when using `fmemopen` (as suggested):

```
char buf[] = "hello";

FILE *fp = fmemopen(buf, strlen(buf), "w");
execl("/usr/bin/echo", "echo",  fp, (char *)NULL);
```

I get mangled output..

Comment: As I understand, you need fmemopen() function.

Comment: You can also [read an write from /dev/shm](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html)

Comment: You are executing another process, you cannot pass a FILE* to it and have it know how to read from that. If your real issue is to execl() another process and have it read data from your memory, there are other ways to do that. (and if the data is reasonably small, the echo example could be done by `execl("/usr/bin/echo", "echo",  buf, (char *)NULL);` If you want to learn how to use fmemopen() though, you can't use it with execl() in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using C and the GNU C Library, or any POSIX compliant implementation, You can use [fmemopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) which works exactly as you expect.

If you want to do this in portable ISO C, fmemopen is unfortunately not available.

There are however examples of libraries doing this in a portable way, eg. https://github.com/Snaipe/fmem.

This makes use of the [funopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/funopen) function which allows associating stream operations with user-supplied functions.

If you target Windows, the situation is a little more complicated, with some insights found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087392/393701.

Comment: [`fmemopen()` is part of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html), so it's pretty portable.