# C DLL working on FILE * called from C# - passing a stream in and out

Tags: c#, c, stream, pinvoke, arrays

I have an issue with calling a C DLL function from my C# code. The C DLL has a function accepting a file name (`const char *`), then opens the file, performs some work on the content (reads through the `FILE *`) and writes the outcome to another file. I'd like to optimize it, so that the disk read/write operations are not performed, since I have the file to be processed already in a memory stream in my C# app. I have a liberty to modify both ends (C# app and C DLL). C# app is .NET 2.0 based.

I thought of extending the DLL so that it has a function that accepts and spits out a byte array, so that I could easily `PInvoke` it. The output part seems easy on the C side - instead from writing to a `FILE *` I could just save the consecutive bytes to an array - but the input seems hard. I don't know how to deal on the C side with the obtained byte array to make it into a memory stream and work on that instead on the physical file stream from this point (I don't want to rewrite the whole DLL to read from byte array instead of `FILE *` - I want most of the DLL internals to remain unchanged, just to wrap it and tweak ins/outs). But actually I don't know, maybe there is a better idea to do that.

So **the question is**: how to turn a byte array in C into a `(FILE *)` without writing it actually to disk and opening a `FILE *` to read this file?
**Alternatively**: how to pass a memory stream from C# through `PInvoke` to a C DLL so that it could be easily recognized on the C side and worked with as a `FILE *` (again, without physical disk writes/reads, in-memory only)?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539537/memory-buffer-as-file/539608) could be the same thing you ask.

Comment: A FILE* can only ever read/write from a physical file, the C Runtime doesn't offer an option to map it to a stream.  You'll have to raise the abstraction in your C code.  There's nothing in the CRT that helps you do this, but there's for example the standard COM IStream interface.  Not much fun in C either, only in C++.

Comment: If you have the liberty to change both, why don't you just change it all to c#?

Comment: @Jodrell: the DLL is quite elaborate, I don't want to rewrite it, rather to reuse it.

Comment: @RedGlow: thanks, part of it worked like a charm, namely using fmemopen with predefined byte array as an underlying buffer (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html)

Answer (score 1):

Named pipes in Windows are handled through memory buffers and are compatible with most file APIs. To operate a pipe use "\\.\pipe" namespace, e.g. name like "\\.\pipe\foo". To create pipe use CreateNamedPipe Win32 API. Use fopen to open it on C side.

Another alternative could be mailslot created by CreateMailSlot API and operated though "\\.\mailslot" namespace. The main difference is operating on datagrams level rather than streams as in case of pipes.