# read gzip stream from SSL socket connection

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, gzip

I have a system where client sends a `gzip` file to a server over regular socket connection. The server consumes the file without writing to disk. The server uses `gzdopen` and `gzread` to read from socket.  I have a requirement to add TLS/SSL layer for secured communication. How to read `gzip` files at server end without writing `SSL_read` to temporary file or very huge chunk of memory ?

Comment: According to the [`zlib` manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html): *"...gzread can be used to read a gzip file that is being concurrently written. Upon reaching the end of the input, gzread will return with the available data. If the error code returned by gzerror is Z_OK or Z_BUF_ERROR, then gzclearerr can be used to clear the end of file indicator in order to permit gzread to be tried again. Z_OK indicates that a gzip stream was completed on the last gzread. Z_BUF_ERROR indicates that the input file ended in the middle of a gzip stream..."*

Comment: Also, if your problem is having a memory buffer but needing a file number or file descriptor, then see [Difference between fmemopen and open_memstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29849749/608639).

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: The easiest solution is to run the current server [behind an SSL/TLS proxy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy)  Why do developers seem to think way too often that the best solution is to write more code, or even worse, to rewrite working code?  [Every problem is not a nail...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Comment: @jww Thanks. I will try that out.