# Open FILE* to a growing memory space

Tags: c++, qt, memory, buffer

The library I am working with requires a FILE* as the input to store an unknown amount of text. Normally I would be able to pass cout as the FILE*, but I want to capture this unknown sized text into a variable instead.

Is there a good way to create a FILE* to a growing sized buffer which is to be filled?

I am aware of something like this -

```
char output[1024] 
FILE *foutput = fmemopen(output, 1024, "w");
```

but from what I understand, this opens a fixed size buffer of 1024 bytes that can be written to.

Comment: Are you looking for something like dynamically allocated memory? Or your issue is related to redirect standard output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539537/memory-buffer-as-file/8908037

Comment: C is no OOP language. You cannot extend/overload operators or extend types. And `FILE` is an implementation-defined opaque type (resp. it should be treated as one).

Comment: @Olaf: `QString` is `C++` not `C`. I guess the `C` tag is only because an answer in `C` would be acceptable.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: The code shown is C, so I commented about C. What is the problem with my comment? Did I say anything it would not be possible in C++?

Comment: Please remove the tag of the unrelated language. Just because you use an example in one language, does not justify tagging with the language. If you want C++ features, why not use C++ streams? They are as much standard in C++ as the C functions are in C.

Comment: Which language does the question want an answer for? C or C++?

Comment: @JeremyP: OP asks about `FILE`, which is C. I'd remove the C++ tag, but apparently the edit waits for acceptance.

Comment: To answer your questions, the content of the answer can be C++ but I need to bring t down to FILE* to work with C code (my project is mixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *ptr = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
FILE *fp = open_memstream(&ptr, &size);
```

Now you can use `fp` with `stdio` functions and access the "printed" output via `ptr`. The buffer is grown automatically and should be `free`d after `fclose`ing the stream.

[`open_memstream`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) is not standard C but specified by POSIX.1-2008. There's an ISO C TR about it though.

For systems, where `open_memstream` isn't available (like macOS), you can implement it using `fopencookie` or `funopen`, which allow you to define your own `fread`, `fwrite`, `fseek` and `fclose` functions, which will be called while operating on the stream. Both aren't standardized (first is a GNU extension, second is BSD-specific).

You could use [BSD libc's implementation](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdio/open_memstream.c) on such systems.

For systems that only implement the API mandated by the C standard, you're out of luck. Best you can do is having the output written into a tempfile (Maybe kept in ramfs or similar) and then read from that.

---

You should only do this if you are interacting with an API that uses `FILE` IO though. If that's not a requirement consider using `std::stringstream` or similar instead.

Comment: I think this is pretty much a `glibc` only answer (OS X does not implement it). I don't think that is a problem for the questioner though because `fmemopen` is pretty much `glibc` only too. I'm not the downvoter btw, in fact, I upvoted.

Comment: @JeremyP `funopen` which is used to implement `open_memstream` is available on OS X. I amended my answer.

Comment: This is what I needed. Just 1 note -- I got a double free corruption after deleting ptr after fclose. I'm guessing fclose already takes care of freeing the resources?

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 POSIX prohibits `fclose` from doing that. What platform are you on?

Comment: CentOS 6.6 Linux version 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 gcc version 4.4.7. EDIT: I revise my answer. I tried it again and I believe I was deleting the FILE* instead of the char* after fclose. Deleting char* worked. Thank you for catching that for me.