# Partially truncating a stream (fstream or ofstream) in C++

Tags: c++, file, truncate, fstream, ofstream

I am trying to partially truncate (or shorten) an existing file, using fstream. I have tried writing an EOF character, but this seems to do nothing.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. There are many functions for moving "up and down" the wrapper hierarchy for `HANDLE<->int<->FILE *`, at least on Windows, but there is no "proper" to extract the `FILE *` from an iostreams object (if indeed it is even implemented with one).

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream) to be of assistance.

Personally I would strongly recommend steering clear of iostreams, they're poorly designed, heavily C++, and nasty to look at. Take a look at [Boost's iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html), or wrap [stdio.h](http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/stdio.h.htm) if you need to use classes.

The relevant function for stdio is [ftruncate()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/ftruncate/).

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/index.html) library defines a portable `truncate` function. For some reason it is not documented, but you can find it [this header file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp).

Comment: `ftruncate` is portable as in Posix.  But it does not use C++ streams of course.

Comment: Yes I meant portable for Posix and Win32.

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on the OS. Most OSes support this, but in different ways. On Windows, there's a `SetEndOfFile()`. On Unix and similar systems, you `lseek` to where you want the file to end, and do an `lwrite` of zero bytes there. Other OSes undoubtedly use other methods.

Comment: Surely on Unix one would use `ftruncate(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I bit the bullet in the end and read the part of the file to be kept to an array then re-wrote it. It's not the best solution - but as the files will always be small I have decided to accept this method.

Comment: Why not just use C file I/O and do it directly, rather than working around the limitations imposed by C++ streams (which seem the wrong tool for your task)?