# Get FILE* from fstream

Tags: c++, io, fstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

Is there a way to obtain a FILE* from an a iostream derived class? Particularly from an fstream?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream

Comment: Sorry. Didn't find that one in my search. Please close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not in a portable way.

GCC's `libstdc++` has a class called `stdio_filebuf` that you can use with a stream, and it does allow you to directly get the associated `FILE*`, but, `stdio_filebuf` is not a `basic_filebuf`, and cannot be used with `basic_fstream`.