# PHP Reading uploaded file by php://fd/

Tags: php, upload, file-descriptor

Is it possibile to read uploaded file by protocol php://fd/?

For example:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('php://fd/1'); // I quess file descriptor (1) is the name of file input ?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I can use "php://input"
I asked becouse I need to get clear text "something" which is in file.
I can use char '\0' to manipulate result but php://fd/ would me simplest way..

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) - [Also this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: :) I know how to upload file.
I am just wonder about this case

Comment: Well, I guess you *could* eat soup with a knife, but why bother when you're given a spoon... :)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**php://fd** expects file descriptor. I think you have to create one with fopen on uploaded file and then use it's id.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_FILES["1"]["tmp_name"]); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I know..
But could you tell me is it possible to use php://fd?
Is name of input is file descriptor?