# Make git status show unmodified/unchanged tracked files?

Tags: git, version-control

Here is a brief snippet example (which you can paste in your Linux terminal), creating a new `git` repository and adding some files to it (using git version 1.7.9.5):

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir myrepo_git
cd myrepo_git/
git init
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email you@example.com
echo "test" > file_tracked_unchanged.txt
echo "test" > file_tracked_changed.txt
echo "test" > file_untracked.txt
git add file_tracked_unchanged.txt 
git add file_tracked_changed.txt
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now, after the initial commit, I want to change the `file_tracked_changed.txt` files, and keep the others (here, only `file_tracked_unchanged.txt`) unchanged for the next commit. Below is a snippet which demonstrates that, and the diverse outputs of `git status` vs `git ls-files` (`git` shell output is prefixed with `#`):

```
echo "test more" >> file_tracked_changed.txt

git status -uno
# # On branch master
# # Changes not staged for commit:
# #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
# #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
# #
# # modified:   file_tracked_changed.txt
# #
# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
git status
# # On branch master
# # Changes not staged for commit:
# #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
# #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
# #
# # modified:   file_tracked_changed.txt
# #
# # Untracked files:
# #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
# #
# # file_untracked.txt
# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
git status -uno --short
#  M file_tracked_changed.txt
git status --short
#  M file_tracked_changed.txt
# ?? file_untracked.txt
git ls-files -v
# H file_tracked_changed.txt
# H file_tracked_unchanged.txt

git add file_tracked_changed.txt

git status -uno
# # On branch master
# # Changes to be committed:
# #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
# #
# # modified:   file_tracked_changed.txt
# #
# # Untracked files not listed (use -u option to show untracked files)
git status
# # On branch master
# # Changes to be committed:
# #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
# #
# # modified:   file_tracked_changed.txt
# #
# # Untracked files:
# #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
# #
# # file_untracked.txt
git status -uno --short
# M  file_tracked_changed.txt
git status --short
# M  file_tracked_changed.txt
# ?? file_untracked.txt
git ls-files -v
# H file_tracked_changed.txt
# H file_tracked_unchanged.txt
```

What I'm looking for, is a command which will show all tracked files in a directory (which `git ls-files -v` does), with their accurate repository status (which `git ls-files` doesn't show, as it shows `H` as status for all tracked files). For instance, I'd like to obtain something like the pseudocode:

```
git status-tracked
# M file_tracked_changed.txt
# . file_tracked_unchanged.txt
```

... where the dot `.` would a symbol indicating a tracked, but unchanged file (if I recall correctly, SVN may use a `U` character for these).

Ultimately, I'd like to also show the status of all files in a directory, as in the pseudocode:

```
git status-tracked-and-untracked
# M file_tracked_changed.txt
# . file_tracked_unchanged.txt
# ?? file_untracked.txt
```

... but it's more important to me to get to the status of all tracked files, as in the pseudo `git status-tracked` above.

Any command in `git`, that already does something like this?

Comment: Many thanks for the comment @Kartik - but that command shows tracked modified + untracked; I'm looking for a command that shows tracked modified + tracked unmodified. Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

Quick one-liner that works on Linux and on a Mac:

`sort -uk 2bi <(git status -s) <(git ls-files | sed 's/^/ . /')`

---

You can wrap this in an convenient alias that also accepts an optional directory path. So under `[alias]` in your `.gitconfig` you can put this:

```
stt = "!f() { cd -- ${GIT_PREFIX}/${1:-.} ; sort -uk 2bi <(git status -s .) <(git ls-files . | sed 's/^/ . /') ; }; f"
```

Then you can use it something like this:

```
$ git stt
$ git stt src/foo
$ git stt ..
```

Comment: Very simple, and very fast. On two large repos I tested, over 10x faster on the first run, and over 100x faster on subsequent runs, when compared with my answer.

Comment: This is nice, and you can add `| grep '^ \. '` to see _only_ the unmodified files.  See also a similar strategy (for listing only unmodified files) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31448015/411282): `git ls-files --modified ; git ls-files ) | sort | uniq -u`

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @sdaau. I've made a few changes so that it runs much faster, and delivers results in the same format as `git status`:

```
git ls-files | while read -r line;
do
    st=$(git status -s "$line");
    if [ -n "$st" ]; then
        echo "$st";
    else
        echo "   $line";
    fi;
done
```

Comment: ^  Very useful, but still somewhat slow, because it runs a git_status for every single file.

Comment: I modified this to accept a list of files passed to `git ls-files` but it still prints nothing for deep ignored files, rather than '??'

Comment: See @hashstat's answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59722589/1488762) for the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307091/make-git-status-show-unmodified-unchanged-tracked-files#comment23348437_16307284), for the `git ls-tree` tip; this is what it shows:

```
git ls-tree --name-status HEAD
# file_tracked_changed.txt
# file_tracked_unchanged.txt
```

... but I want statuses `:)`

OK, here is a solution, calling both `ls-files` and `status`, and interleaving them with a bit of `bash` parsing:

```
git ls-files -cdmoskt --abbrev=8 | while read -r line; do \
  fn=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\s\(\w\+\)/\1/'); \
  st=$(git status -s "$fn" | printf "%-02s " $(sed 's/\([[:print:]]\+\)\s.*/\1/')); \
  echo "$st- $line"; \
done
```

If you run this as in the OP example, you get:

```
git ls-files -cdmoskt --abbrev=8 | while read -r line; do fn=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\s\(\w\+\)/\1/'); st=$(git status -s "$fn" | printf "%-02s " $(sed 's/\([[:print:]]\+\)\s.*/\1/')); echo "$st- $line"; done
# ?? - ? file_untracked.txt
# M  - H 100644 52e7a08e 0  file_tracked_changed.txt
#    - H 100644 9daeafb9 0  file_tracked_unchanged.txt
```

... which is basically what I wanted. (I'll post back here if I have luck in converting this into a `git` alias).

---

EDIT: here as `git` alias (for `~/.gitconfig`):

```
  ls-fstatus = "! cd $PWD/$GIT_PREFIX; git ls-files -cdmoskt --abbrev=8 | while read -r line; do \
    fn=$(echo \"$line\" | sed \"s/.*\\s\\([[:print:]]\\+\\)/\\1/\"); \
    st=$(git status -s "$fn" | printf \"%-02s \" $(sed \"s/\\([[:print:]]\\+\\)\\s.*/\\1/\")); \
    echo \"$st- $line\"; \
  done "
```

... so one can just call `git ls-fstatus` in a given git repo subdirectory.

Comment: This doesn't handle paths with spaces. By added quotes around the argument to cd it works: `cd \"$PWD/$GIT_PREFIX\";`

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [@RogerDueck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647655/236195), I made a script that executes `git ls-files` and `git status` only once each. It runs about 15 times faster on my repo with ~ 1700 files, just under 2 sec.

**EDIT:** Added a number of fixes and some unittests, moved to GitHub: https://github.com/frnhr/git-fullstatus

Sample output:

```
 M some/file
D  another/file
 D more/files/blahblah
A  this/is/an/added/file/i/think
   an/unchanged_file
   another/unchanged_file
```

Comment: Excellent! Why `file=\`echo "${line:3}" | xargs\`` instead of just `file="${line:3}"`?

Answer (score 0):

[frnhr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31221544/1655607) didn't work for me on macOS, because it has an older version of bash. Here's a similar idea in perl. Instead of qsort, it just merges the two lists, which are already sorted (except ignored files at the end).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

# --ignored means something different to ls-files than to status
my @ls_args = grep( ! m/^(-i|--ignored)/, @ARGV );

my @files  = split( /\n/, `git ls-files  @ls_args` );
my @status = split( /\n/, `git status -s @ARGV` );

# merge the two sorted lists
while (@files and @status) {
    $status[0] =~ m/^.. (.*)/;
    my $cmp = $1 cmp $files[0];
    if ($cmp <= 0) {
        print shift @status, "\n";
        if ($cmp == 0) {
            shift @files;
        }
    }
    else {
        print "   ", shift @files, "\n";
    }
}
# print remainder
print map {"   $_\n"} @files;
print map {"$_\n"} @status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that takes a list of files to check, and outputs *something* for every file passed in -- modified, unmodified ('  '), or ignored ('??').

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sorted=$(printf '%s\n' $(realpath --relative-to . "$@") | sort)
for f in $sorted; do
    st=$(git status -s "$f");
    lsf=$(git ls-files "$f");
    if [ -n "$st" ]; then
        echo "$st";
    elif [ -n "$lsf" ]; then
        echo "   $lsf";
    else
        echo "?? $f"
    fi;
done
```

And a one-liner git alias for the same thing:

```
[alias]
        file-status="!f() { sorted=$(printf '%s\\n' $(realpath --relative-to . \"$@\") | sort); for f in $sorted; do st=$(git status -s \"$f\"); lsf=$(git ls-files \"$f\"); if [ -n \"$st\" ]; then echo \"$st\"; elif [ -n \"$lsf\" ]; then echo \"   $lsf\"; else echo \"?? $f\"; fi; done }; f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only show unmodified/unedited tracked files/paths:

bash/zsh

```sh
$ git ls-files | grep -vf <( git status -s | grep '^[^?]' | cut -c4- )
```

```sh
$ git ls-tree --name-status HEAD |
    grep -vf <( git status -s | grep '^[^?]' | cut -c4- )
```

1. pipe ls-files/ls-tree to grep
2. `grep -v -f`

   - `-v` exclude/filter out
   - `-f` read output of `git status -s | grep '^[^?]' | cut -c4-` as a [file descriptor][1] starting with `<(`, ending with `)`
3. - `[^?]` grep first character cannot be a `?`
   - `cut -c4-` cut fourth character until end of line

```
$ time zsh -c " git ls-files |
    grep -v -f <( git status -s | grep '^[^?]' | cut -c4- )"
fileA
fileB
dirA/file1
zsh -c "git ls-files| grep -v -f <( git status -s | grep '^[^?]' | cut -c4- )"  0.02s user 0.03s system 69% cpu 0.073 total
```

```
$ time zsh -c "git ls-tree --name-status HEAD |
    grep -v -f <( git status -s | grep '^[^?]' | cut -c4- )"
fileA
fileB
zsh -c   0.02s user 0.03s system 93% cpu 0.057 total
```

(note: it's fine to not escape newlines after `|`, but if the preferred style is to escape, I'm happy to edit)
[1]: [What are file descriptors, explained in simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms)

Answer (score -1):

```
git status -s | egrep -v '^\?\?'
```

This filters out lines that start with `??`, that is, the untracked files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Andomar - but unfortunately, that command doesn't show the tracked but unmodified files, which is what I am asking. Cheers!

Comment: `git ls-tree --name-status HEAD` should do what you want, but it silently ignores the `-status` part :)

Comment: Many thanks, @Andomar - great tip, I had no idea about `ls-tree`, but as you say, the statuses are not shown - so I just posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16308182/277826) which "interleaves" the statuses from `git`s `status` and `ls-files`. Cheers!