# How to list all unchanged (tracked) files?

Tags: git, git-status

I unzipped an older "git-image" onto my git repository and most of the files have been changed. I would like to know which files remained untouched. How to list these files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make git status show unmodified/unchanged tracked files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307091/make-git-status-show-unmodified-unchanged-tracked-files)

Comment: Have the sets of files themselves changed?

Comment: @Mureinik, okay, but where's the correct answer in that duplicate?

Comment: I just deleted my `git ls-files --no-modified` answer. As you pointed out correctly, the `--no-modified` switch does in fact nothing. Sorry!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't find anything purely git, but with some bash it is possible:

```
( git ls-files --modified ; git ls-files ) | sort | uniq -u
```

**explanation**

- `git ls-files` lists all files tracked by git
- `git ls-files --modified` lists all the **modified** files tracked by git
- the rest is some bash scripting to remove the duplicates from both lists.

Comment: For a similar idea to show both modified and unmodified files in a format like `git status` see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59722589/411282).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, if you unzip a archive, you may also won't use git but `unzip -u`? It echos (the name of) all updated files and you may extract the list with sed or something if you like...