# git ls-files without the ignored or whatever would git add -A gives plus all source

Tags: git

I need a list of all files that are unchanged, all files that are staged if any, and all files that would be staged if next command were `git add -A`.

Tried `git ls-files -co` (cached and others). But that seems to give a list which also includes the ignored files.

Is there a reliable command/option combination that I can obtain such a list? (to be used in a script).

Comment: Would adding `--exclude-standard` work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all unchanged (tracked) files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447637/how-to-list-all-unchanged-tracked-files)

Comment: you can take a look at my answer in the related question on how to show the unchanged files...