# Hudson : "yes: standard output: Broken pipe"

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins, hudson, pipe

I need to run a shell script in hudson. That script needs an answer from the user. To give an automatic answer I did the following command line :

```
yes | ./MyScript.sh
```

This works well in Ubuntu terminal. But when I use the same command in the Hudson job, the script will be automated and do all the needed work, but at the end, I get these two lines of error :

```
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
yes: write error
```

And this causes the failure to my Hudson job.

How should I change my command line to work well in Hudson?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> But how would you explain that I dont get this error while running the script *locally*, but I get the error when running it *remotely* from a Hudson job?

When you are running it in a terminal (*locally*); `yes` is killed by `SIGPIPE` signal that is generated when it tries to write to the pipe when `MyScript.sh` has already exited.

Whatever runs the command (*remotely*) in Hudson traps that signal (set its handler to `SIG_IGN`, you can test it by running `trap` command and searching for SIGPIPE in the output) and it doesn't restore the signal for new child processes (`yes` and whatever runs `MyScript.sh` e.g., `sh` in your case). It leads to the write error (`EPIPE`) instead of the signal. `yes` detects the write error and reports it.

You can simply ignore the error message:

```
yes 2>/dev/null | ./MyScript.sh
```

You could also report the bug against the component that runs the pipeline. The bug is in not restoring SIGPIPE to the default handler after the child is forked. It is what programs expect when they are run in a terminal on POSIX systems. Though I don't know whether there is a standard way to do it for a java-based program. `jvm` probably raises an exception for every write error so not-dying on SIGPIPE is not a problem for a java program.

It is common for daemons such as hudson process to ignore SIGPIPE signal. You don't want your daemon to die only because the process you are communicating with dies and you would check for write errors anyway.

Ordinary programs that are written to be run in a terminal do not check status of every `printf()` for errors but you want them to die if programs down the pipeline die e.g., if you run `source | sink` pipeline; usually you want `source` process to exit as soon as possible if `sink` exits.

`EPIPE` write error is returned if `SIGPIPE` signal is disabled (as it looks like in hudson's case) or if a program does not die on receiving it (`yes` program does not defined any handlers for `SIGPIPE` so it should die on receiving the signal).

> I don't want to ignore the error, I want to do the right command or fix to get rid of the error.

*the only* way [`yes` process stops if it is killed or encountered a write error](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/yes.c). If `SIGPIPE` signal is set to be ignored (by the parent) and no other signal kills the process then `yes` receives write error on `./MyScript.sh` exit. There are no other options if you use `yes` program.

**`SIGPIPE` signal and `EPIPE` error communicate the exact same information -- pipe is broken**. If `SIGPIPE` were enabled for `yes` process then you wouldn't see the error. And only because you see it; nothing new happens. It just means that `./MyScript.sh` exited (successfully or unsuccessfully -- doesn't matter).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggested solution. But I worry that this solution might redirect any error to /deb/null (broken pipe or other). So, I rather need a command that fixes the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Farah: if you don't want to ignore the error. What would you like to do with it if you detect one?

Comment: I agree with the edit you have just done, +1. But how would you explain that I dont get this error while running the script locally, but I get the error when running it remotely from a Hudson job?

Comment: @Farah: your last question is what my answer from the very beginning tried to explain.

Comment: Thank you, nice explanation for what's going on. You deserve the bounty.

Comment: Brilliant answer, very insightful

Comment: Thank you,very use

Answer (score 3):

I had this error, and my problem with it is not that it output `yes: standard output: Broken pipe` but rather than it returns an error code.

Because I run my script with [bash strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) including `-o pipefail`, when yes "errors" it causes my script to error.

### How to avoid an error

The way I avoided this is like so:

```
bash -c "yes || true" | my-script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the yes program to pipe to the script? or echo yes to the script? If the process is working through jenkins, add "; true" to the end of your shell command.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. But I should not ignore the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since `yes` and `./MyScript.sh` can each be run in an explicit subshell, it is possible to background the `yes` command, send `yespid` to the `./MyScript.sh` subshell and then implement a trap on `EXIT` there to manually terminate the `yes` command. (The trap on `EXIT` should always be implemented in the subshell of the last command of a piped commmand sequence).

```
# avoid hangup or "broken pipe" error message when parent process set SIGPIPE to be ignored
# sleep 0 or cat /dev/null: do nothing but with external command (for a shell builtin command see: help :)
(
trap "" PIPE
( (sleep 0; exec yes) & echo ${!}; wait ${!} ) | 
   ( 
     trap 'trap - EXIT; kill "$yespid"; exit 0' EXIT
     yespid="$(head -n 1)"
     head -n 10  # replacement for ./MyScript.sh
   )
echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
)
```

If you want to exit the `yes` subshell with exit code `0` you can do this as well:

```
# avoid hangup or "broken pipe" error message when parent process set SIGPIPE to be ignored
# set exit code of yes subshell to 0
(
trap "" PIPE
   (
      trap 'trap - TERM; echo "kill from yes subshell ..." 1>&2; kill "${!}"; exit 0' TERM 
      subshell_pid="$(bash -c 'echo "$PPID"')"
      (sleep 0; exec yes) & echo "${subshell_pid}"; wait ${!} 
   ) | 
   ( 
      trap 'trap - EXIT; kill -s TERM "$subshell_pid"; exit' EXIT
      subshell_pid="$(head -n 1)"
      head -n 10  # replacement for ./MyScript.sh
   )
echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
)
```

Comment: Especially the latter script looks overly complicated. You could use `wait ${!} || :` in the first one to make the exit status be 0. And it is better to use `read -r yespid` than `yespid="$(head -n 1)"`. Can you be sure that the pid is written first to the pipe when you have `sleep 0` there before `yes`? It is not a problem with `yes`, but in general case you should hide possible error of `kill`, if the left side of pipe exits first.

Comment: In my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588332/111181) to a related question I address the issues I mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

The command yes being running in an infinite loop I supposed that this might be the solution :

```
yes | head -1 | ./MyScript.sh #only one "Y" would be output of the command yes
```

But, I got the same error.

We can redirect the error to /dev/null as suggested by @J.F. Sebastian, or enforce that the command is correct by this :

```
yes | head -1 | ./MyScript.sh || yes
```

But, this suggestions were less appreciated. And so, I had to create my own named pipe, as follow :

```
mkfifo /tmp/my_fifo #to create the named pipe
exec 3<>/tmp/my_fifo #to make the named pipe in read and write mode by assigning it to a file descriptor
echo "Y" >/tmp/my_fifo #to write into the named pipe, "Y" is the default value of yes
./MyScript.sh </tmp/my_fifo #to read from the named pipe
rm /tmp/my_fifo #remove the named pipe
```

I'm expecting more valuable solutions with greater explainations.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms) it is an explaination for a file descriptor in linux.

Thanks

Comment: 1st command should produce the same error. If you don't understand it; [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20624315/4279) failed. 2nd command starts `yes` again if `./MyScript.sh` fails. Why would you do it? (Remember the exit code of a pipeline is a exit code of the *last* command (`yes | cmd` gives you exit status of `cmd` whatever exit status of `yes`).

Comment: 3rd set of commands (with mkfifo) is a perverted way to write `echo "Y" | ./MyScript.sh; true` It produces only *one* `"Y"` (the default for `yes` is infinite *as many as needed* `"y"` (lowercase)) and It *hides exit status* for `./MyScript.sh`. If one "Y" is enough for `./MyScript.sh` then use `echo Y | ./MyScript.sh`.