# Gunicorn + nginx - Ignoring EPIPE

Tags: python, nginx, server, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

I have an nginx-gunicorn-flask setup running on google compute 
and I keep getting the following from gunicorn:

```
[2019-04-19 20:50:49 +0000] [3345] [DEBUG] POST /
[2019-04-19 20:50:49 +0000] [3345] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
```

out of 100 requests about 23 come out like that. In the access log only 23 requests show and they're all 200.

from nginx access logs show a 504 and in the error logs I see this:

```
2019/04/19 20:50:49 [error] 3097#3097: *295 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while sending request to upstream, client: ip, server: , request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/user/Server/server.sock/", host: "ip"
```

I tried setting

```
proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
```

on the location on nginx and `--timeout 300` in gunicorn based on [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816215/gunicorn-nginx-timeout-problem) but it didn't help.

The message from gunicorn isn't really helping determine the cause and I didn't find any info about it

Been trying to solve this for a while and I'd appreciate any ideas. Also each of these requests take about 1-2 seconds and jmeter shows a huge latency until the results show up.

Looking at gunicorn's code this is a errno.EPIPE exception having to do with the socket...

Comment: i have same issue. i think it's due to some execution.

Comment: Do you host Nginx and app server on the same host? Can you show your Nginx and Gunicorn config?

Comment: somewhat related (on the topic of services and sigpipe): [Hudson : “yes: standard output: Broken pipe”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20573282/4279)

Comment: im getting those log messages when workers are restarted and take some time to come up, while health-checks are running against nginx. Im only guessing, but it could be that gunicorn worker-manager queues up requests during worker restart, then worker processes the requests but the client connection is already closed when the response is ready. As said, just a guess. The messages disappear when workers are up and waiting.

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar issues and timeout error, in addition with increasing timeout value, add Nginx config `proxy_ignore_client_abort on;` check this [thread](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1695) and [Nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_client_abort)

```
proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Gunicorn` and `NGINX` are running on the same server, this could be a permission issue.

Check which user the Gunicorn server is running your application as with `ps aux | grep gunicorn`, then you can change the permissions accordingly.

Stop `NGINX`, and run the commands below

```
chown gunicorn_user_here.nginx /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy -v
rm /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/* -R
chmod 777 /var/lib/nginx/tmp -v
```

Start `NGINX` and check the logs.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the hard drive was full and that was causing the issue.