# Is it safe to delete catalina.out if Tomcat is stopped?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, catalina.out

My catalina.out file has 37 GB which seems to prevent my app running correctly on a linux (Centos) server since the file takes up all my server space. I never thought that a log file can get this big. Would it be safe (I have no test server to try) to stop Tomcat (Tomcat9) and just delete catalina.out? Is a new catalina.out file created when I start Tomcat again?

Or would it be better to do

```
 sudo echo > catalina.out
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094871/how-to-clear-catalina-out-without-disabling-further-logging). What actually does this command do?

I need to stop the Tomcat for an update of my app from time to time anyway and I don't need to store the older log files. So what is the best way to keep catalina.out small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely **truncate** (i.e. replace the content with an empty string) the `catalina.out` file even if Tomcat is running, which can be done manifold:

```sh
cat > catalina.out
# or
truncate catalina.out
```

Deleting the file, while Tomcat is down also works, but on a running Tomcat it would have a big side effect: Tomcat will still be appending data to the deleted file and the space will not be released until Tomcat shuts down.

In order to keep `catalina.out` small you should:

- remove the `ConsoleHandler` from `logging.properties` (`.handlers` and `handlers`): the data logged to the `ConsoleHandler` is also logged to `catalina.<date>.log`,
- make sure the logging system of your applications doesn't log to the standard output/standard error, but to a properly rotated file.

Comment: Since the file is so big, I don't want to do anything while Tomcat is running. I can easily stop the tomcat. You say that I can safely delete the file when Tomcat is stopped. Is a new catalina.out created if I start tomcat again?

Comment: Yes, the file is created if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts again and it is totally safe. In case if you remove the `catalina.out` while `tomcat` is running, it will keep on logging to `catalina.out` which is removed already (reference of the file is hold by the `tomcat`) hence the space will not be released. So you will need to restart the `tomcat` sever to release the space. It is not recommended.

Delete/ Move `catalina.out` when `tomcat` server is stopped will not have any problem at all.

But in critical applications running on `tomcat` used by public, this won`t be a good solution since there will be a downtime.

Actually you can clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping tomcat with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

To keep `catalina.out` smaller and get rid of older logs, either one of the following ways can be used:

1. You could use the above `Linux` command and add it to a `CronScheduler`
   to run daily/ weekly/ monthly or yearly as preferred.
2. Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
   in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
   Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
   file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
   info on this.