# Is it possible to pass input to a running service or daemon?

Tags: linux

I want to create a Java console application that runs as a daemon on Linux, I have created the application and the script to run the application as a background daemon. The application runs and waits for command line input.

My question:

Is it possible to pass command line input to a running daemon?

Comment: Sorry, the title is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, the title is wrong. The idea is to create a daemon that works like nginx or tomcat. For example, the daemon is running, when an user type into the console: "service MyserviceID --create test", the daemond must be abble to read this command and acts. All this without restarting the daemond

Comment: If you are writing the server process (daemon), then you have several options. You can use `socket`, `named pipes` or even `stdin`. If the server process or daemon is written by somebody else and it guarantees that it reads from stdin, you can send input via `/proc/<processID>/fd/0`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Linux, all running processes have a special directory under [`/proc`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) containing information and hooks into the process. Each subdirectory of `/proc` is the PID of a running process. So if you know the PID of a particular process you can get information about it. E.g.:

```
$ sleep 100 & ls /proc/$!
...
cmdline
...
cwd
environ
exe
fd
fdinfo
...
status
...
```

Of note is the `fd` directory, which contains all the [file descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5256599/113632) associated with the process. `0`, `1`, and `2` exist for (almost?) all processes, and `0` is the default stdin. So writing to `/proc/$PID/fd/0` will write to that process' stdin.

A more robust alternative is to set up a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) connected to your process' stdin; then you can write to that pipe and the process will read it without needing to rely on the `/proc` file system.

See also [Writing to stdin of background process](https://serverfault.com/q/188936/134800) on ServerFault.

Comment: this needs 1000x more updoots

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer above didn't quite work for me, so here's my implementation.
For context I'm running a Minecraft server on a Linux daemon managed with `systemctl`. I wanted to be able to send commands to `stdin` (StandardInput).

First, use `mkfifo /home/user/server_input` to create a FIFO file somewhere (also known as the 'named pipe' solution mentioned above).

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minecraft.sh
StandardInput=file:/home/user/server_input
```

Then, in your daemon `*.service` file, execute the bash script that runs your server or background program and set the [StandardInput](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardInput=) directive to the FIFO file we just created.
In `minecraft.sh`, the following is the key command that runs the server and gets input piped into the console of the running service.

```
tail -f /home/user/server_input| java -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -jar /path/to/server.jar nogui
```

Finally, run `systemctl start your_daemon_service` and to pass input commands simply use:

`echo "command" > /home/user/server_input`

Creds to the answers given on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process)

Comment: my server freezes on: Started BungeeCord Server.

Comment: I would need more context than that. Maybe make a new post & link me here?

Comment: I needed this answer in a Minecraft context years ago lol. Now I’m here looking for the same answer in a different context