# Use python output as an input for another daemon process

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, daemon

I wonder if I can use stdout from python code as an input for another daemon process such as gnome-calculator for instance and if so how could I achieve that.

The goal is to automate the interaction with an app (not with gnome-calculator) later on (pen-testing would be one application).

I know how I would do that with two processes that are both launched from the terminal, for instance:

```
python ps1.py | python ps2.py
```

I've also read that you can interact with processes using `proc/$pid` directory, but I don't understand how would one do that either.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? What problems have you run into with your solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand how would I redirect python output from terminal to a already running daemon process. I know how it can be done with a pipe and two processes launched from the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pass input to a running service or daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732425/is-it-possible-to-pass-input-to-a-running-service-or-daemon)

Comment: Perhaps what's confusing you is the `$PID` part -- you should replace it with the actual `pid` (process id) of the deamon that you want to write to. Of course, the default `fd` (file descriptor) corresponding to the `stdout`, i.e., 0, might not be used by the deamon in question, but then you should just try with other `fd`s opened by that process.

Comment: No, that's not what is confusing me. So I opened up gnome-calculator and then I ran    ```python3 ~/Desktop/ps1.py > /proc/7527/df/0```  7527 being gnome-calculator PID, ps1.py just prints 12, shouldn't I be seeing the output on the running gnome-calculator?

Comment: Or say ```echo 12 > /proc/7527/df/0```

Comment: I don't know, is this how gnome-calculator works? (Most likely a typo, but it should be `/proc/7527/fd/0`.)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know that either... I'll try it on some other programs. You're right it is a typo and thanks tons, I've definitely learnt something new!!