# Trying to print the values from two files

Tags: bash, shell

This shell :

```
for i in $(cat file1.txt) and j in $(cat File2.txt)       
do
    echo " portname=$i domainid=$j "       
done
```

NOT getting proper output .

Can you suggest to how to use it

Comment: What was the input, current output and what did you expect? See also [mcve].

Comment: Input 
File1 :port1 
         PORT2
FILE2
           1
           2
Output:
portname=PORT1 domainid=
portname=PORT2 domainid=
portname=and domainid=
portname=j domainid=
portname=in domainid=
portname=1 domainid=
portname=2 domainid=

Comment: There is an [edit] link that allows you to update your question. Don't add useful info in the comments.

Comment: Using `for` loop with 2 `in` you obtain a cartesian product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using file descriptor redirection :

```
while read -r i && read -r j <&3
do
    echo " portname=$i domainid=$j ";
done < file1.txt 3<File2.txt
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `3` stand for at the first and last line ?

Comment: `3` is a custom file descriptor (`0` is stdin `1`is stdout `2`is stderr ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms

Answer (score 2):

Using `paste` command :

```
paste file1.txt File2.txt |
while read -r i j
do
    echo " portname=$i domainid=$j "
done
```