# why /dev/stdout is "1

Tags: linux, gcc

```
SEGMENT .data ; nothing here
SEGMENT .text ; sauce
global _start
_start:
            pop ECX ; get ARGC value
            mov EAX, 4 ; sys_write()
            mov EBX, 1 ; /dev/stdout
           ;^^^^^^^^^^^
            mov EDX, 1 ; a single byte
            int 0x80
            mov EAX, 1 ; sys_exit()
                    mov EBX, 0 ; return 0
            int 0x80
SEGMENT .bss ; nothing here
```

why mov EBX, ""1"" ; /dev/stdout ?
where document I can find "1" ?

Comment: ("In C, stdin, **stdout**, and stderr are FILE*, which in UNIX respectively map to file descriptors 0, **1** and 2." - [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257718))

Comment: Here is a good survey of the history: [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) from wikipedia. The article goes back to the 1950's and discusses Unix design, and explains why the streams were standardized and their values.

Answer (score -1):

On unix systems, a process normally have 3 common  I/O channels connected to it, called stdin/stdout/stderr. These have the corresponding file descriptor values 0, 1 and 2.

This is documented at: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html (See also the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) )