# Python - How to use relative paths with os.replace?

Tags: python, macos

I am using the `os.replace` function to rename a folder. The folder will remain in the same parent directory.

```
parent_dir = '/Users/my_Username/Desktop/'
old_name = 'foo'
new_name = 'bar'
os.replace(parent_dir + old_name, parent_dir + new_name)
```

This code works, but feels a little redundant, especially when using long variable names and when calling this function multiple times.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace),

> This function can support specifying src_dir_fd and/or dst_dir_fd to supply paths relative to directory descriptors.

However, I cannot figure out how to pass in the relative path of both folders. I thought it would be something like this:

```
os.rename(old_name, new_name, src_dir_fd=parent_dir)
```

But that doesn't work.

**How do I pass in a relative path?**

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
import os

parent_dir = '/Users/my_Username/Desktop/'
old_name = 'foo.txt'
new_name = 'bar.txt'

with os.open(parent_dir, os.O_RDONLY) as fd:
    os.replace(old_name, new_name, src_dir_fd=fd)
```

Option `src_dir_fd` accepts  a *file descriptor* (fd), intead of actual path. There is good description in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#files-and-directories).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did read the documentation you linked in your answer, but it's still not entirely clear to me what a file descriptor is. How to I transform a file path into a file descriptor and what does one look like?

Comment: @PeterSchorn check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms