# Why isn't lseek changing value? (C)

Tags: c, lseek

```
unsigned int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

printf("%u\n", file);
printf("%u\n", elf.offset);

lseek(file, elf.offset, SEEK_SET);

printf("%u", file);
```

OutPut:

```
3
52
3
```

Shouldn't `file` be set to `52`?

Comment: No: `file` is a file descriptor.  The position of the file pointer has nothing to do with that.  Use the return value from `lseek` to obtain the actual position.  Read the documentation for `lseek`, and `open` for that matter.  You can get the current position by calling `lseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR)`

Comment: if `file` contains the offset the how can multiple files can be opened in a single program?

Comment: `open()` return an `int` result. Why are you assigning that result to an `unsigned int` object? (I have no idea why you'd expect `file` to be set to 52.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon successful completion, the resulting offset, as measured in bytes from the beginning of the file, shall be returned.

try this `printf("lseek_offset: %d\n", lseek(file, elf.offset, SEEK_SET));`

Answer (score 1):

`file` is a file descriptor. When you print it, you print the file descriptor, not the offset. When you `lseek` it to an offset of 52, the file descriptor is still 3, so it still prints 3.

You can read more about file descriptors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms).

Answer (score 1):

yon confuse `file` with `file decriptor`. The latter is just a non-negative integer that identifies an open file.
maybe this example can help you to understand these two concepts better:

```
char buf[8];
int main(){
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    off_t offset = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
    printf("first read when offset = %d : %s\n", (int)offset, buf);

    offset = lseek(fd, 32, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
    printf("second read when offset = %d : %s\n", (int)offset, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
first read when offset = 0 : 0000000

second read when offset = 32 : 4444444
```

here are the contents of `test`:

```
0000000\n    
1111111\n
2222222\n
3333333\n
4444444\n
```