# Why is calling file write() method not working?

Tags: python

I have some Python3 code that opens a file in write mode, writes something to it, and then closes the file. The filename is an `int`. For some reason, the code doesn't work as expected. When I run the `f.write()` statement, a `6` is printed to the screen. And when I run the `f.close()` statement, the string that was supposed to be written is printed to the screen.

```
>>> f = open(2, 'w')
>>> f.write('FooBar')
6
>>> f.close()
FooBar>>>
>>>
```

I checked the directory that I ran this in and the file (named `2`) was not created. Can anyone explain what is going on? I suspect it has to do with the filename being an `int`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's probably treating the int as a reference to a stream like stdout.  Dare I ask why you tried to open a file whose name is an int?

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux, 2 is the [file descriptor for stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms).

Comment: @BrenBarn `open(2)` wraps file descriptor 2 as a file object.

Comment: @AKX: Yes, but the remark at the end of the question ("the file (named 2) was not created") indicates the questioner somehow expects the integer to be used as a filename, not a descriptor.

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, I misread... everything in a hurry. :)

Comment: Please read the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for the function you are calling **before** asking questions here. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not done an adequate amount of research before asking the question.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing in a file descriptor number (2 for stderr).

1. See [the documentation for `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), emphasis mine:

   > `file` is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened **or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped**.
2. As to why nothing happens before `.close()` (or `.flush()`: Your stream is line buffered, and you're not writing a newline.

   ```
   f = open(2, 'wb', buffering=0)
   ```

   to disable buffering.

If you wish to write to a file called `'2'`, you must pass a string.

```
f = open('2', 'w')
```

Comment: You might want to also address why `6` is displayed in response to the `f.write()` call.  That is, of course, the number of characters written by the call, which is what `f.write()` returns.  in this case, its the length of the string `FooBar`.

Comment: @CryptoFool: The reason for that is also explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=write#io.TextIOBase.write) although admittedly it's *much* harder to find if you do a [simple documentation search](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=write&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to a file name (type `str`) `open` also accepts a file descriptor (type `int`). `2` is the file descriptor of `stderr` on Linux, so you are opening the standard error stream for writing, so everything you write to that file object will appear in your terminal/console! The reason it appears only after you do `file.close()` is that by default the write content isn't immediately written to the file but rather kept in a buffer which gets written only when a newline `\n` is encountered in the write content, and of course when the file is closed. You can force a writeout to file by calling `file.flush()`.

The reason for the `6` you get on screen is that the return value of `file.write` is always the number of characters that has been written.

In case you wanted to create a file with *the name `2`* in the current working directory, you need to wrap the `2` in quotes:

```py
>>> f = open("2", 'w')
>>> f.write('FooBar')
6
>>> f.close()
>>>
```