# File Descriptor In Linux

Tags: linux, io, operating-system, computer-science

How file descriptors in Linux System are actually applied to perform read and write operations does the I/O Module uses file descriptor information to write or read data to the appropriate file

Comment: Does [What are file descriptors, explained in simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17741176/6771046) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

File descriptor is a number. It is an index into **an array of opened files**, that exists in kernel space. There is one such array for each process (unless they decide to share).

That array contain pointers to a **file struct** — [a kernel structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L961) representing an opened file, device or network socket. The struct contains many bookkeeping fields, and can even be extended by a driver that owns the file. But the most important field is **file operations** — this field contains a list of function pointers to the actual code behind the system calls - one for each system call. Yes, the same system calls can call different code — depending on the type of the file: regular files will call functions from the filesystem driver, network sockets will call functions from the network driver, etc.

So the overall process is this:

1. You call the system call, you give it the *file descriptor.*
2. The syscall indexes the *array of opened files* of the current process. If the entry with that index is not opened - return error.
3. The syscall gets the *file struct* pointer, and retrieves the function pointer to a requested operation. If that operation is not supported - return error.
4. Call the function. Pass the file struct pointer, and all parameters to the function.

---

You may ask — why so many complications? Why not just pass a `file *` to the syscall? It is for security — if the user program can somehow manipulate the file struct, or point the kernel to a fake one — it can gain access to any file, completely bypassing any security checks. That's why it is important that there is a level of indirection, that is fully within the kernel-protected memory — which the user programs have no access to.