# What is difference between file descriptor and file pointer?

Tags: c, operating-system, file-descriptor, file-pointer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a file descriptor and file pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423628/whats-the-difference-between-a-file-descriptor-and-file-pointer)

If I open file like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("mr32.txr","r");
```

then `fp` is file pointer or file descriptor? What is difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fp is a FILE pointer

File pointer:

1. It is high level interface
2. Passed to fread() and fwrite() functions
3. Includes buffering,error indication and EOF detection,etc.
4. Provides higher portability and efficiency.

File descriptor:

1. Low/Kernel level handler
2. passe to read() and write() of UNIX System Calls
3. Doesn't include buffering and such features
4. Less portable and lacks efficiency

based on this [link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/98191)

Answer (score 4):

It's a pointer to a `FILE` structure, if that's what you're asking.  A file descriptor is an integer.  The `FILE` structure and its related APIs are part of the C standard.  File descriptors and their related functions are not.  In practice you can use either set of functions interchangeably, though there are some notable differences in default behaviour here and there.  You can read the man pages to figure out which functions take which sort of parameters.  On systems that have file descriptors, you can usually use the `fdopen(3)` function to get a `FILE` structure from an open file descriptor and `fileno(3)` to go the other way.

Comment: It's worth noting that FILE is an opaque pointer (the memory it points to is meaningless to the code using the interface.) It's also worth noting that POSIX open returns a file descriptor.

Comment: And worth noting that `fdopen` *creates a new* `FILE` object (which needs to be closed, and upon closing which the file descriptor is also closed), while `fileno` simply *returns the existing* file descriptor underlying a `FILE`.

Answer (score 2):

`FILE` is a struct that contains information about the file, including the file descriptor.