# Closing a C++ FILE pointer which uses a file descriptor from Java

Tags: android, java-native-interface, fclose, fdopen, parcelfiledescriptor

When using a file descriptor in native code, which has been obtained from a [ParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor), should the native side use **fclose** after an **fdopen**?

The [documentation states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#getFd()) that the ParcelaleFileDescriptor instance owns the file descriptor, and it should be closed through it. I don't know the impact of closing the native FILE pointer before closing the file descriptor.

**Pseudocode:**

```
1) JAVA:
    // Obtain the file descriptor and pass it to the native method
    ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor  = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
    nativeMethod(descriptor.getFD());

2) C++:
    void nativeMethod(const int fd)
    {
        FILE* fp = fdopen(fd, "wb");    

        ..... // do something

        fclose(fp); // Close the file pointer <-- Is this valid?
    }

3) JAVA:
    // Back from the native method, close the file descriptor
    descriptor.close();
```

Comment: *I don't know the impact of closing the native FILE pointer before closing the file descriptor.* Test it and find out?  Or just use `write()`/`read()` on the file descriptor directly.

Comment: was the write ok, i am just getting -1 for write in native side ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423628/whats-the-difference-between-a-file-descriptor-and-file-pointer

Comment: how will this work, pid of java app is differnt from native app , how will native app access  java fd ?