# what kinds of types can we specify in `fdopen()`, and which part of the type is valid?

Tags: c, linux, io

APUE says

> With fdopen, the meanings of the type argument differ slightly.
>
> The descriptor has already been opened, so **opening for writing** does
>   not truncate the ﬁle. (If the descriptor was  created  by  the open
>   function,  for  example,  and  the  ﬁle  already  existed,  the
>   O_TRUNC ﬂag  would  control  whether  the  ﬁle  was  truncated.  The
>   fdopen function cannot simply truncate any ﬁle it opens for writing.)
>
> Also, **the standard I/O append mode** cannot create the ﬁle (since the
>   ﬁle has to exist if a descriptor refers to it).

In general, when we call `fdopen()` on a file descriptor returned from `open()`, 
what kinds of types can we  specify in `fdopen()`?
Must the type specified in `fdopen()` be exactly the same as the mode specified in `open()`?
Can the type specified in `fdopen()` be a subset, superset, or neither subset nor superset of the mode specified in `open()`?

If there is no restriction on the types specified in `fdopen()` with respect to the mode specified in the previous `open()`, which part of the type specified in `fdopen()` is valid, and which part isn't (i.e. is ignored)?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a file descriptor and file pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2423628/608639)

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fdopen.html) specifies:

> The application shall ensure that the mode of the stream as expressed by the `mode` argument is allowed by the file access mode of the open file description to which `fildes` refers.

The Rationale section goes a little further:

> The meanings of the `mode` arguments of `fdopen()` and `fopen()` differ. With `fdopen()`, open for write (`w` or `w+`) does not truncate, and append (`a` or `a+`) cannot create for writing. The `mode` argument formats that include a `b` are allowed for consistency with the ISO C standard function `fopen()`. The `b` has no effect on the resulting stream. Although not explicitly required by this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, a good implementation of append (`a`) mode would cause the `O_APPEND` flag to be set.

Since file descriptors can be opened in a wide variety of ways (`open()`, `socket()`, etc.), and there can be custom device drivers that have different restrictions, it's not really possible to provide a general specification of the relationship between the `open()` mode and the `fdopen()` mode.

But it should be pretty safe to assume that if the file descriptor is open for writing, you should be able to use mode `w`, and if it's open for reading you can use mode `r`.

Comment: Thanks. What happens  if the file descriptor is open for writing and you  use mode r in fopen(), and if it's open for reading and you  use mode w in fopen()?

Comment: The results are unspecified, and likely depends on the device driver.

Comment: When the specification says that you **shall** do something, and you don't do it, the consequeces are undefined.