# My function doesn't write the characters properly to stdout

Tags: c

I've written this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int concatenate(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    concatenate(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}

int concatenate(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *temp;
    int sz;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((temp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file %s", argv[i]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } 

        fseek(temp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        sz = ftell(temp);
        rewind(temp);

        fwrite(stdout, 1, sz, temp);
        fclose(temp);
    }
}
```

And I want to know why the program is printing rare characters to `stdout` and how to solve the problem to no prevent to commit it in the future. Thank you in advance.

By the way, I'm passing normal .txt files to the program and I'm currently working on Ubuntu.

Comment: See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3p.html

Comment: This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805607/what-does-a-file-pointer-point-to-in-c

Comment: Writing to ```stdout``` is what ```printf``` does for you. Besides what exactly ```fwrite (stdout, 1, sz, temp)``` is supposed to do?

Comment: I wonder if you have posted the correct code! Perhaps you have tried different ways of calling `fwrite` and ended up posting a version of the code that doesn't do what you describe!? Should it really be: `fwrite (temp, 1, sz, stdout);` ? It's not the correct way but it matches what you describe (unlike the current posted code).

Comment: What rare characters? This program can never write anything to the standard output.

Comment: To put it differently... The posted code tries to **write to the file**. It's not writing to `stdout`

Comment: To correct your program read about https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh It's true that `printf` write to `stdout` but you can also write to `stdout` using `fwrite`. You just have to do it correct... the code in the question is **not** doing it correct.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: Unrelated - don't `fprintf()` partial lines like that; always write a complete line (ending in `\n`).  Even better, use `perror(argv[i])` to include a more specific message.

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behavior here:

```
    fwrite(stdout, 1, sz, temp);
```

The prototype for `fwrite` is:

```
size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
              FILE * restrict stream);
```

Your call attempts to write to the stream pointed to by `temp` a number of bytes equal to `1 * sz` pointed to by `stdout`.

- Writing to a stream open for reading has undefined behavior. It is unlikely, although not impossible, that this call outputs anything to `stdout`. Maybe you tried a different parameter order such as `fwrite(temp, 1, sz, stdout)` which attempts to output `sz` bytes from the contents of the `FILE` structure pointed to by `temp` to `stdout` and would show bizarre output if anything at all.
- There might not be `sz` bytes accessible via the `FILE` pointer. As a matter of fact, `FILE *` are opaque pointers; the `FILE` type may be an incomplete type without an actual definition, so no actual bytes may be readable at that address. Reading bytes from `stdout` has undefined behavior.
- Even `sz = ftell(temp)` does not produce a reliable result as the stream was opened in text mode.  On Unix systems, this would evaluate to the file length in bytes, but on legacy systems with obscure text file handling, the result can only be passed to `fseek()` with `SEEK_SET` mode for later repositioning; its numerical value is meaningless.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int concatenate(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        FILE *temp;
        int c;

        if ((temp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file %s: %s\n",
                    argv[i], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } 

        while ((c = getc(temp)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);

        fclose(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO what he wanted was to print the sizes of the files passed as arguments, not to concatenate them, he is using `fseek()` and `ftell()` to get the last position in the file and tries to print that.  Despite the function named `concatenate` 8-.

Comment: @LuisColorado: I'm afraid I disagree: IMHO, the OP intended to read the contents of the file into a memory allocated buffer and write that to `stdout`.  This approach works for all but extremely large files, but requires opening the input file in binary mode and causes line termination corruption when writing the binary contents to `stdout` in text mode on legacy systems.  In a simpler alternative, one could read the file in a local array in a loop using `fread` and write the contents read with `fwrite`.

Comment: I accept your disagree, but I see no buffer, no copy at all... just a fseek to the end and an ftell to get the position, then the OP triest to print it out to stdout.  No buffers, no copies no nothing... has he edited his post?

Comment: @LuisColorado: you are correct, none of what is needed is there. Maybe he was confused about files and arrays and assumes the file contents was accessible via the `FILE *` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
        fwrite(stdout, 1, sz, temp);
```

probably what you want is:

```
        printf("%u\n", sz);
```

`fwrite` will print the binary representation of the data you pass to it (and you also pass it incorrectly, not as a pointer reference)

That will print the files sizes to `stdout` which is what you apparently do in your code.  Despite of the call being called `concatenate()` this is something strange and probably has directed other colleagues to show you how to concatenate files.  You need to explain a bit more.  Please, edit your question to clarify.