# How to use file descriptor to divert write-to-file in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, language-interoperability

I would like to use some C code that uses a file descriptor. 
Background is that I would like to read some data from cgraph library.

```
public extension UnsafeMutablePointer where Pointee == Agraph_t {
   func saveTo(fileName: String)  {
      let f = fopen(cString(fileName), cString("w"))
      agwrite(self,f)
      fsync(fileno(f))
      fclose(f)
   }
}
```

I would like to have the file output, but without writing to a temp file. Hence, I would like to do something like this:

```
public extension UnsafeMutablePointer where Pointee == Agraph_t {
    var asString: String  {
        let pipe = Pipe()
        let fileDescriptor = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        fileDescriptor.pointee = pipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor
        agwrite(self, fileDescriptor)
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            return output  
        }  
        return ""
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, resulting in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS within agwrite(,). What do I need to do instead?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>`? `fopen` returns a `File *`.

Comment: What's the exact type signiture of `agwrite`, as imported by Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File descriptors and file pointers [are not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34217180/3141234). It's confusing, and made even more frustrating by the fact that `FILE *` is really hard to Google because of the symbol.

You need to `fdopen` the file descriptor (`pipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor`), to receive a `FILE *` (`UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>` in Swift). This is what you then pass to `agwrite`.

It's important to `fclose` the file pointer when you're done writing to it, otherwise `.readDataToEndOfFile()` will never terminate. I made a helper function to ensure the `fclose` can't be forgetten. It's possible that `agwrite` closes the file pointer itself, internally. If that's the case, you should delete this code and just give it the result of `fdopen`, plain and simple.

```
import Foundation

public typealias Agraph_t = Int // Dummy value

public struct AGWriteWrongEncoding: Error { }

func agwrite(_: UnsafeMutablePointer<Agraph_t>, _ filePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>) {
    let message = "This is a stub."

    _ = message.withCString { cString in
        fputs(cString, stderr)
    }
}

@discardableResult
func use<R>(
    fileDescriptor: Int32,
    mode: UnsafePointer<Int8>!,
    closure: (UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>) throws -> R
) rethrows -> R {
    // Should prob remove this `!`, but IDK what a sensible recovery mechanism would be.
    let filePointer = fdopen(fileDescriptor, mode)!
    defer { fclose(filePointer) }
    return try closure(filePointer)

}

public extension UnsafeMutablePointer where Pointee == Agraph_t {
    func asString() throws -> String {
        let pipe = Pipe()

        use(fileDescriptor: pipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, mode: "w") { filePointer in
            agwrite(self, filePointer)
        }

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

        guard let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw AGWriteWrongEncoding()
        }  
        return output  
    }
}

let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Agraph_t>.allocate(capacity: 1) // Dummy value
print(try ptr.asString())
```

Several other things:

1. Throwing an error is probably a better choice than returning `""`. Empty strings aren't a good error handling mechanism. Returning an optional would also work, but it's likely to always be force unwrapped, anyway.
2. `readDataToEndOfFile` is a blocking call, which can lead to a bad use experience. It's probably best that this code be run on a background thread, or use a [`FileHandle.readabilityHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/1412413-readabilityhandler) to asynchronously consume the data as it comes in.

Comment: excellent! From the description of my trouble to find information to the solution. Thank you