# What are "cerr" and "stderr"?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, stderr

What is the difference between them and how are they used?
Can anyone point me to examples?

Specifically, how do you "write" to the stream in both cases and how do you recover and output (i.e. to the screen) the text that had been written to it?

Also, the "screen" output is itself a stream right? Maybe I don't understand streams well enough. This can also be saved to a file of course, I know. Would all of these use `fprintf` / `fscanf`, etc?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`cerr` is the C++ stream and `stderr` is the C file handle, both representing the standard error output.

You write to them the same way you write to other streams and file handles:

```
cerr << "Urk!\n";
fprintf (stderr, "Urk!\n");
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "recover" in this context, the output goes to standard error and that's it. The program's not meant to care about it after that. If you mean how to save it for later, from outside the program, see the next paragraph.

By default, they'll go to your terminal but the output can be redirected elsewhere with something like:

```
run_my_prog 2>error.out
```

And, yes, the "screen" output is a stream (or file handle) but that's generally only because `stdout/cout` and `stderr/cerr` are connected to your "screen" by default. Redirection will affect this as in the following case where nothing will be written to your screen:

```
run_my_prog >/dev/null 2>&1
```

(tricky things like writing directly to `/dev/tty` notwithstanding). That snippet will redirect both standard output and standard error to go to the bit bucket.

Comment: The other difference is that standard error is either not buffered (i.e. auto-flush on every write) or line-buffered (auto-flush on every `\n`) regardless of whether it refers to an interactive device or not. In contrast, standard output is fully buffered if (and only if) it does not refer to an interactive device.

Comment: Well, technically that's a difference between stdout and stderr (or cout and cerr), not cerr and stderr :-)

Answer (score 15):

> What is the difference between them

`stderr` is a `FILE*`, and part of the standard C library.  `cerr` is an `ostream`, and part of the standard C++ library.

> Also, the "screen" output is itself a
>   stream right?

Yes, it is.  But there are actually *two* streams that write to the screen by default: `stdout`/`cout` is for normal output and `stderr`/`cerr` is for error messages.  This is useful for redirection: You can redirect `stdout` to a file but still have your error messages on the screen.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the `FILE* stderr` pointer from the `std::ostream cerr` object? (something like `cerr.rdbuf()->bla`)

Comment: @alfC: There is not a standard way to do so.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream .

Comment: yes, I answered there http://stackoverflow.com/a/19749019/225186 . I think the most elegant answer is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33612982/225186