# How can I align the numbers that the console outputs at the same position

Tags: c++, console, alignment, text-alignment

I'm trying to write a very simple C++ program which outputs a lookup table with the corresponding `x` and `y` values of sinus function. The code that I wrote is the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double hw = 4.0;
    int nsteps = 30;
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    const double maxx = hw * PI;
    const double deltax = maxx / nsteps;
    double x = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nsteps; i++) {
        const double f = sin(x);
        cerr << x << "\t" << f << endl;
        x = x + deltax;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program is working, but my problem is, that the values are not getting aligned properly as showed in the following picture
[image: Image of program output]
So is there any way, to achieve that the second column of the values will actually be a column and all the values are aligned at the same position? What could I use instead of `\t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer provides an incorrect solution because the alignment is not set correctly. I would use a function to handle the formatting:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void printxy(double x, double y, int width){
    cout << setw(width) << x << "\t";
    if (y < 0) cout << "\b";
    cout << setw(width) << y << "\n";
}

int main(){
    double hw = 4.0;
    int nsteps = 30;
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    const double maxx = hw * PI;
    const double deltax = maxx / nsteps;
    double x = 0.0;

    int decimals = 6;
    int width = 8;    //Adjust as needed for large numbers/many decimals
    cout << std::setprecision(decimals);
    cout << std::setw(width);
    cout.setf(ios::left);

    for (int i = 0; i < nsteps; i++) {
        const double y = sin(x);
        printxy(x, y, width);
        x = x + deltax;
    }
}
```

The output is now formatted correctly:

```
0               0
0.418879        0.406736
0.837757        0.743144
1.25664         0.951056
1.67551         0.994522
2.09439         0.866026
2.51327         0.587787
2.93215         0.207914
3.35103        -0.207909
3.76991        -0.587783
4.18879        -0.866024
4.60767        -0.994521
5.02654        -0.951058
5.44542        -0.743148
5.8643         -0.406741
6.28318        -5.30718e-06
6.70206         0.406731
7.12094         0.743141
7.53982         0.951055
7.95869         0.994523
8.37757         0.866029
8.79645         0.587791
9.21533         0.207919
9.63421        -0.207904
10.0531        -0.587778
10.472         -0.866021
10.8908        -0.994521
11.3097        -0.951059
11.7286        -0.743151
12.1475        -0.406746
```

I would also discourage the use of `cerr` for these kinds of printing operations. [It is intended for printing errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200117/what-are-cerr-and-stderr/3200136#3200136) Use `cout` instead (it works the same way for all practical purposes).

I should also mention that `endl` is a ticking bomb: it flushes the output, meaning that the internal buffer of the stream is written out (be it the console, a file or whatever). When applications scale and become more IO intensive, this can become a significant performance problem: the buffer that is intended to increase the IO performance is potentially unused due to frequent `endl` insertions. The solution is to use the newline character `'\n'`.

Comment: beautiful. Thanks a lot. Would you mind explaining why `endl` is a ticking bomb?

Comment: @Max Sorry about that, I somehow forgot. I've edited the answer to explain this. Also, calling it "a ticking bomb" was a bit exaggerated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::setprecision()` to set count number for decimal after point, and `std::setw()` to set width of output length. Include `<iomanip>` needed, example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double hw = 4.0;
    int nsteps = 30;
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    const double maxx = hw * PI;
    const double deltax = maxx / nsteps;
    double x = 0.0;
    cerr << std::setprecision(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < nsteps; i++) {
        const double f = sin(x);
        cerr << std::setw(20) << x << std::setw(20) << f << endl;
        x = x + deltax;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
                   0                   0
          0.41887867          0.40673632
          0.83775733          0.74314435
            1.256636          0.95105619
           1.6755147          0.99452204
           2.0943933          0.86602629
            2.513272          0.58778697
           2.9321507          0.20791411
           3.3510293         -0.20790892
            3.769908         -0.58778268
           4.1887867         -0.86602363
//...
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The next 19 lines (which you did not include in your answer) are not formatted properly.