# How to Access File Descriptor of Open File

Tags: c++, stream, filestream, file-descriptor

Is there any way to access the file descriptor of a file opened in c++?  So ...

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
      ifstream inputFile( "file.txt",ios::in );
      cout << inputFile.fileDesc << endl;//made up call
      return 0;
 }
```

The question is, does something like fileDesc exist for ifstreams?  If not how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The question is why do you want to do this? If you explain your rational then maybe an alternative can be found that solves your actual problem.

Comment: The reason that I need the file descriptor is that I need to run fstat() on a file as some time after it has been opened.  I realize that I could use stat() on the filename but I am using fstat() so I can get stats on streams as well.  I just wanted a concise method that could be used for the reserved stream descriptors (0(STDIN), 1(STDOUT), and 2(STDERR) and for files that are opened.

Comment: EDIT: I realize that ifstream is a stream, but it doesn't have a reserved filedes like the previosly mentioned IO streams.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

Comment: I want to get the file  descriptor in Linux so I can [`flock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to get to the FILE* from the stream then the answer is basically "you can't" as stated by more enlightened people than me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream).

Comment: Well, I plan on running fstat() on the file descriptor, but I could use stat() on the actual filename.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [open()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html):

*The open function creates and returns a new file descriptor for the file named by filename.*

Comment: This is not a good idea, because `"file.txt"` might refer to a completely different file meanwhile.