# Using SQLite with std::iostream

Tags: c++, sqlite, iostream

Does someone know a wrapper which would allow SQLite to load its data from an `std::iostream`?

To be more explicit:

```
std::fstream dataStream("database.sqlite");
...
sqlite3_open(...something using dataStream...);
```

I want to use streams because of their modularity: being able to load a file while it is still being downloaded from the network, decompressing data on-the-fly, etc.

It should be possible by using [sqlite3_open_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) after registering your own [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html). After one hour of implementing (badly-documented) functions, my first attempts got me a weird "out of memory" error from SQLite, and I thought I would ask here if someone knows an existing implementation before spending hours debugging mine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: sqlite3_open* only accepts file names, not even `FILE*` pointers

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. The name you pass to VFS can be anything, it's essentially a callback argument. That will identify the `fstream`. The most efficient way to perform I/O on the fstream, and the only way to implement several operations in http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/io_methods.html, is to get a file descriptor from it. If you want sqlite to work with `stringstream`, that's another story.

Comment: I'd like to make it work for any derivate of `iostream`, I'm currently working on it

Comment: @Tomaka: There is no way to truncate an `fstream`, and interprocess locking won't work. Aside from that, just fill in all those functions and see how it works. By the way, do you have a reference to a stream implementation that decompresses data on-the-fly? I'm making revisions to GCC's fstream/basic_filebuf and would like an example of such, if it is implemented with the locale/codecvt interface…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I also saw the problem with truncation but for the moment it doesn't get called ; as for the decompression on-the-fly I didn't make an implementation yet, the only derivates of iostream I made for the moment don't need locales (PNG, JPEG, Ogg decoding, and interacting with a socket)

Comment: When I open my db, SQLite opens the stream and reads it to discover that it is empty. Everything fine until now. But when I execute a `CREATE TABLE` followed by an `INSERT`, SQLite opens a journal file, writes it, closes it, checks the original stream (which is still empty) and fails because it couldn't find the table... this is weird ; it also does a lot of weird things, like locking multiple times the same file, repeatly checking the same file's size, deleting a file with a "-wal" suffix, etc.

Comment: Ok it took me one hour of debugging to figure out that the write function should return SQLITE_OK and not the number of bytes written, contrary to fwrite

Comment: @Tomaka: Well, the important thing is that you're figuring it out. Keep up the good work! By the way, for your other streams, are you extending `basic_streambuf` or `streambuf` or `iostream`? `streambuf` extension is always preferable because functions are allowed to slice the stream object…

Comment: It's working! I'm current adding comments and cleaning a bit the code and I'll post it

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the main class is derivating from `basic_istream` and/or `basic_ostream` but it uses an internal class which derivates from `basic_streambuf` ; the real implementation is located in this internal class, the main class is just here for convenience

Comment: @Tomaka: Cool, that sounds like the right way to do it. Look forward to seeing your code :v) .

Comment: @Tomaka: Make sure that you let the SQLite developers know about this work on either `sqlite-users` or `sqlite-dev` (see http://www.sqlite.org/support.html for addresses). That's definitely the sort of place for this, and they'll be able to tell you whether your code has a chance of working in production or not. (For the record it scares me…)

Comment: @Donal Fellows: that's a code I started writing yesturday, it is far from ready to go in production! I'll tell them when the code is a bit cleaner and more tested (also I'm always a bit anxious when writing to code gurus like them)

Comment: @Tomaka: Well, doing this sort of thing is a good step on the road to being a code guru yourself, you know, and I know some of those guys personally so do speak up; they *are* approachable for this grade of thing.

Comment: @Tomaka: i saw you got a little bit of a beating on sqlite-users... not entirely negative though.  i think your work looks promising and personally i look forward to being able to use streams with sqlite.  keep us posted and keep up the good work.

Comment: @rev: As they said, streams as not really the good tool for this job ; my opinion now is that you can use them if you want to easily implement something, but not as a replacement for a real VFS implementation in an application where they are used intensively ; but I'll continue to work on it when I have some time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since nobody seems to know an existing implementation, I coded one myself :)

How does it work:

- you have to call `sqlite3_open_v2` with the name of the custom file system as the last parameter
- in this file system, a 'file' is equivalent to a `std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>`
- the name of the file you pass to `sqlite3_open_v2` is the [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm)'ing of a `std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>*` ; the open function of the file system will make a copy of this `shared_ptr`

You may wonder why I used lexical_cast while I could have used `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&stream)`. This is because SQLite calls `strcpy` on the file name, and this could cause buffer overflow or data truncation issues. Also SQLite takes our file name and appends "-journal" or "-wal" in order to generate temporary file names. This would cause other problems.

The code is really far from being perfect (some things are not implemented) but it's working for some of the basic operations I tried (creating a table, inserting some entries and selecting).

EDIT: temporary tables and commit/rollbacks are working too

```
void openConnection(std::shared_ptr<std::iostream> stream) {
    sqlite3* ptr = nullptr;

    // lexical_cast'ing the pointer to the stream into a string
    // take extra care that it is a shared_ptr<iostream> and not istream or ostream or whatever
    std::stringstream filenameStream;
    filenameStream << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&stream);
    if (sqlite3_open_v2(filenameStream.str().c_str(), &ptr, 0, getIostreamVFSName().c_str()) != SQLITE_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error(sqlite3_errmsg(ptr));

    // ...use 'ptr' here...
}

// this function registers our custom VFS and return its name
std::string getIostreamVFSName() {
    // a mutex protects the body of this function because we don't want to register the VFS twice
    static std::mutex mutex;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    // check if the VFS is already registered, in this case we directly return
    static const char* vfsName = "iostream_vfs_handler";
    if (sqlite3_vfs_find(vfsName) != nullptr)
        return vfsName;

    // this is the structure that will store all the custom informations about an opened file
    // all the functions get in fact pointer to an sqlite3_file object
    // we give SQLite the size of this structure and SQLite will allocate it for us
    // 'xOpen' will have to call all the members' constructors (using placement-new), and 'xClose' will call all the destructors
    struct File : sqlite3_file {
        std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>      stream;         // pointer to the source stream
        int                                 lockLevel;      // level of lock by SQLite ; goes from 0 (not locked) to 4 (exclusive lock)
    };

    // making sure that the 'sqlite3_file' structure is at offset 0 in the 'File' structure
    static_assert(offsetof(File, pMethods) == 0, "Wrong data alignment in custom SQLite3 VFS, lots of weird errors will happen during runtime");

    // structure which contains static functions that we are going to pass to SQLite
    // TODO: VC++2010 doesn't support lambda function treated as regular functions, or we would use this
    struct Functions {
        // opens a file by filling a sqlite3_file structure
        // the name of the file should be the offset in memory where to find a "std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>"
        // eg. you create a "std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>" whose memory location is 0x12345678
        //      you have to pass "12345678" as the file name
        // this function will make a copy of the shared_ptr and store it in the sqlite3_file
        static int xOpen(sqlite3_vfs*, const char* zName, sqlite3_file* fileBase, int flags, int *pOutFlags) {

            // filling a structure with a list of methods that will be used by SQLite3 for this particular file
            static sqlite3_io_methods methods;
            methods.iVersion = 1;
            methods.xClose = &xClose;
            methods.xRead = &xRead;
            methods.xWrite = &xWrite;
            methods.xTruncate = &xTruncate;
            methods.xSync = &xSync;
            methods.xFileSize = &xFileSize;
            methods.xLock = &xLock;
            methods.xUnlock = &xUnlock;
            methods.xCheckReservedLock = &xCheckReservedLock;
            methods.xFileControl = &xFileControl;
            methods.xSectorSize = &xSectorSize;
            methods.xDeviceCharacteristics = &xDeviceCharacteristics;
            fileBase->pMethods = &methods;

            // SQLite allocated a buffer large enough to use it as a "File" object (see above)
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            fileData->lockLevel = 0;

            // if the name of the file doesn't contain a lexical_cast'ed pointer, then this is not our main DB file
            //  (note: the flags can also be used to determine this)
            if (zName == nullptr || strlen(zName) != sizeof(void*) * 2) {

                assert(flags | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
                // if this is not our main DB file, we create a temporary stringstream that will be deleted when the file is closed
                // this behavior is different than expected from a file system (where file are permanent)
                //   but SQLite seems to accept it
                new (&fileData->stream) std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>(std::make_shared<std::stringstream>(std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary));

            } else {
                // decoding our pointer, ie. un-lexical_cast'ing it
                std::stringstream filenameStream(zName);
                void* sharedPtrAddress = nullptr;
                filenameStream >> sharedPtrAddress;
                // our pointer points to a shared_ptr<std::iostream>, we make a copy of it
                new (&fileData->stream) std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>(*static_cast<std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>*>(sharedPtrAddress));
            }

            assert(fileData->stream->good());

            // I don't really know what to output as flags
            // the "winOpen" implementation only sets either "readwrite" or "readonly"
            if (pOutFlags != nullptr)
                *pOutFlags = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE;
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xClose(sqlite3_file* fileBase) {
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            assert(!fileData->stream->fail());

            // we have to manually call the destructors of the objects in the structure
            //   because we created them with placement-new
            fileData->stream.~shared_ptr();
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xRead(sqlite3_file* fileBase, void* buffer, int quantity, sqlite3_int64 offset) {
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            assert(fileData->stream);
            assert(fileData->stream->good());

            fileData->stream->sync();

            // we try to seek to the offset we want to read
            fileData->stream->seekg(offset, std::ios::beg);
            // if this fails, we'll just tell SQLite that we couldn't read the quantity it wanted
            if (fileData->stream->fail()) {
                fileData->stream->clear();
                memset(static_cast<char*>(buffer), 0, quantity);
                return SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ;
            }

            // reading data
            fileData->stream->read(static_cast<char*>(buffer), quantity);
            fileData->stream->clear();

            // if we reached EOF, gcount will be < to the quantity we have to read
            // if this happens, SQLite asks us to fill the rest of the buffer with 0s
            const auto gcount = fileData->stream->gcount();
            if (gcount < quantity) {
                memset(static_cast<char*>(buffer) + gcount, 0, static_cast<size_t>(quantity - gcount));
                return SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ;
            }

            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xWrite(sqlite3_file* fileBase, const void* buffer, int quantity, sqlite3_int64 offset) {
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            assert(!fileData->stream->fail());

            fileData->stream->sync();

            // contrary to reading operating, SQLite doesn't accept partial writes
            // either we succeed or we fail
            fileData->stream->seekp(offset, std::ios::beg);
            if (fileData->stream->fail()) {
                fileData->stream->clear();
                return SQLITE_IOERR_WRITE;
            }

            fileData->stream->write(static_cast<const char*>(buffer), quantity);

            if (fileData->stream->fail()) {
                fileData->stream->clear();
                return SQLITE_IOERR_WRITE;
            }

            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xTruncate(sqlite3_file* fileBase, sqlite3_int64 size) {
            // it is not possible to truncate a stream
            // it makes sense to truncate a file or a buffer, but not a generic stream
            // however it is possible to implement the xTruncate function as a no-op
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xSync(sqlite3_file* fileBase, int) {
            // the flag passed as parameter is supposed to make a difference between a "partial sync" and a "full sync"
            // we don't care and just call sync
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            return fileData->stream->sync();
        }

        static int xFileSize(sqlite3_file* fileBase, sqlite3_int64* outputSize) {
            // this function outputs the size of the file, wherever the read pointer or write pointer is

            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            assert(!fileData->stream->fail());

            // we don't care about restoring the previous read pointer location,
            //   since the next operation will move it anyway
            *outputSize = fileData->stream->seekg(0, std::ios::end).tellg();
            assert(*outputSize != -1);

            if (fileData->stream->fail())
                fileData->stream->clear();

            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xLock(sqlite3_file* fileBase, int level) {
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            assert(level < std::numeric_limits<decltype(fileData->lockLevel)>::max());
            fileData->lockLevel = level;
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xUnlock(sqlite3_file* fileBase, int level) {
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            assert(level >= 0);
            fileData->lockLevel = level;
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xCheckReservedLock(sqlite3_file* fileBase, int* pResOut) {
            // this function outputs "true" if the file is locked,
            //   ie. if its lock level is >= 1
            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);
            *pResOut = (fileData->lockLevel >= 1);
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xFileControl(sqlite3_file* fileBase, int op, void* pArg) {
            // this function is bit weird because it's supposed to handle generic operations
            // the 'op' parameter is the operation code, and 'pArg' points to the arguments of the operation

            auto fileData = static_cast<File*>(fileBase);

            switch(op) {
                case SQLITE_FCNTL_LOCKSTATE:
                    // outputs the current lock level of the file in reinterpret_cast<int*>(pArg)
                    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(pArg) = fileData->lockLevel;
                    break;

                case SQLITE_FCNTL_SIZE_HINT:
                    // gives a hint about the size of the final file in reinterpret_cast<int*>(pArg)
                    break;

                case SQLITE_FCNTL_CHUNK_SIZE:
                    // gives a hint about the size of blocks of data that SQLite will write at once
                    break;

                // some operations are not documented (and not used in practice),
                //   so I'll leave them alone
                case SQLITE_GET_LOCKPROXYFILE:      return SQLITE_ERROR;
                case SQLITE_SET_LOCKPROXYFILE:      return SQLITE_ERROR;
                case SQLITE_LAST_ERRNO:             return SQLITE_ERROR;
            }

            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xSectorSize(sqlite3_file*) {
            // returns the size of a sector of the HDD,
            //   we just return a dummy value
            return 512;
        }

        static int xDeviceCharacteristics(sqlite3_file*) {
            // returns the capabilities of the HDD
            // see http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_iocap_atomic.html
            return SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC | SQLITE_IOCAP_SAFE_APPEND | SQLITE_IOCAP_SEQUENTIAL;
        }

        static int xDelete(sqlite3_vfs*, const char* zName, int syncDir) {
            // deletes a file ; this is called on 'journal' or 'wal' files
            // these files are treated temporary by 'xOpen' (see above) and are destroyed when 'xClose' is called anyway
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xAccess(sqlite3_vfs*, const char* zName, int flags, int* pResOut) {
            // depending on the value of 'flags':
            //   * outputs true if the file exists
            //   * outputs true if the file can be read
            //   * outputs true if the file can be written
            // we handle all cases at once by returning true only if the file is the name of our main database
            *pResOut = (strlen(zName) == sizeof(void*) * 2);
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xFullPathname(sqlite3_vfs*, const char* zName, int nOut, char* zOut) {
            // this function turns a relative path into an absolute path
            // since our file names are just lexical_cast'ed pointers, we just strcpy
            strcpy_s(zOut, nOut, zName);
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xRandomness(sqlite3_vfs*, int nByte, char* zOut) {
            // this function generates a random serie of characters to write in 'zOut'
            // we use C++0x's <random> features
            static std::mt19937 randomGenerator;
            static std::uniform_int<char> randomDistributor;

            for (auto i = 0; i < nByte; ++i)
                zOut[i] = randomDistributor(randomGenerator);
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xSleep(sqlite3_vfs*, int microseconds) {
            std::this_thread::sleep(std::chrono::microseconds(microseconds));
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xCurrentTime(sqlite3_vfs*, double* output) {
            // this function should return the number of days elapsed since
            //   "noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar"
            // I picked this constant from sqlite3.c which will make our life easier
            static const double unixEpoch = 2440587.5;

            *output = unixEpoch + double(time(nullptr)) / (60.*60.*24.);
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

        static int xCurrentTimeInt64(sqlite3_vfs*, sqlite3_int64* output) {
            // this function should return the number of milliseconds elapsed since
            //   "noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar"
            // I picked this constant from sqlite3.c which will make our life easier
            // note: I wonder if it is not hundredth of seconds instead
            static const sqlite3_int64 unixEpoch = 24405875 * sqlite3_int64(60*60*24*100);

            *output = unixEpoch + time(nullptr) * 1000;
            return SQLITE_OK;
        }

    };


    // creating the VFS structure
    // TODO: some functions are not implemented due to lack of documentation ; I'll have to read sqlite3.c to find out
    static sqlite3_vfs readStructure;
    memset(&readStructure, 0, sizeof(readStructure));
    readStructure.iVersion = 2;
    readStructure.szOsFile = sizeof(File);
    readStructure.mxPathname = 256;
    readStructure.zName = vfsName;
    readStructure.pAppData = nullptr;
    readStructure.xOpen = &Functions::xOpen;
    readStructure.xDelete = &Functions::xDelete;
    readStructure.xAccess = &Functions::xAccess;
    readStructure.xFullPathname = &Functions::xFullPathname;
    /*readStructure.xDlOpen = &Functions::xOpen;
    readStructure.xDlError = &Functions::xOpen;
    readStructure.xDlSym = &Functions::xOpen;
    readStructure.xDlClose = &Functions::xOpen;*/
    readStructure.xRandomness = &Functions::xRandomness;
    readStructure.xSleep = &Functions::xSleep;
    readStructure.xCurrentTime = &Functions::xCurrentTime;
    //readStructure.xGetLastError = &Functions::xOpen;
    readStructure.xCurrentTimeInt64 = &Functions::xCurrentTimeInt64;


    // the second parameter of this function tells if
    //   it should be made the default file system
    sqlite3_vfs_register(&readStructure, false);

    return vfsName;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Why do you use placement new on the `shared_ptr` rather than initializing it from `nullptr` with `reset`? Also, it might be easier (and less overhead) to save and use the streambuf object rather than the stream. The stream's error bits are getting in the way, and you aren't using its added functionality.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The default constructor of the `shared_ptr` is not called (sqlite just does a malloc), and althought `reset` may work in this particular case I don't think it's a good idea to call a function on an uninitialized object ; as for using the `streambuf` I usually see this object as an 'implementation hack' and I consider `iostream` as the real object that we should interface (but this is debatable)

Comment: Well, they do different jobs. `streambuf` just does buffering, while `iostream` provides formatting. Anyway, unless the overhead or the sticky errors are a problem, changing over would be premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks for this! It really helped me with writing my own VFS layer for a custom object.