# Construct ofstream from stdio file

Tags: c++, linux, io, iostream

Is it possible to create an ofstream object from a given stdio file (old-style C file handle)? Preferably without closing and re-opening the file.

The purpose for this is I have a stdio file and a library I'm using takes a stream object.

Comment: Not portably I think... Otherwise check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream

Comment: @par Not necessary to have it portable, this is for linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to construct a c++ fstream from a POSIX file descriptor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2746168/440558)

Comment: If you're at liberty to modify the library, you could try something [like this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In your cited example, one could just use `tempnam` instead and open the file by string. In any case, it's a Bad Idea becuase of buffering issues.

Answer (score 1):

If using boost is an option, and the library takes `std::basic_ostream` (as opposed to an `std::ofstream`) you could use a [File Descriptor Sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html) to wrap your file descriptor, construct a [stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream) from of it, and pass it to your target library.