# The right way to send text to a pipe in C++

Tags: c++, pipe

I opened a pipe to a program that reads text input.

This is what I am currently doing

```
FILE* p = popen("myprogram", "w");
string myBuff;
//write something to myBuff
fprintf(p, "%s\n", myBuff.c_str());
```

This is what I want to do

```
 p = popen("myprogram", "w");
 p << "my text" << endl;
```

Does Boost have something for this? I would assume this is a frequently encountered problem, how is it usually solved?

Comment: What is `File`? I think GCC ships with a stream-type object that wraps a C `FILE*`, which may be useful, but it's not part of the standard library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Construct ofstream from stdio file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073846/construct-ofstream-from-stdio-file)

Comment: It is not immediately obvious as to why this is a duplicate. The solution to my problem could be pipe specific; for example I am looking into using Boost.Process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost has the Interprocess library which facilitates communication between processes. They also have in their sandbox, as an unofficial library, the [Process](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/) library that facilitates inter-process communication using the standard pipes.

Answer (score 4):

A quick and dirty solution that won't involve Boost would be to simply overload `operator<<` for your `FILE*` type.

```
FILE* operator<<(FILE* fptr, const std::string& input_string)
{
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", input_string.c_str());
    return fptr;
}
```

This won't work with the stream modifiers like `std::endl`, etc., but as noted, it gets the job done in a quick-and-dirty way.  There's nothing wrong with Boost per-se, but I think for just trying to gain the ability to use `operator<<` syntax, it's a bit heavy.

Comment: Is there some massive performance hit when doing this? Or is this performance hit the same as one would find using streams?

Comment: Why would there be a massive performance hit?  Both C++ streams and the libc functions for I/O have to go through the same kernel calls, so the performance of both interfaces should be very similar in the end.