# Make fprintf to write to std::stringstream

Tags: stringstream, printf

Function `fprintf` writes to `FILE*`. I have a debugPrint function which writes to stringstream. I don't want to change my function for it is used at many places and it would break the code.

How can I pass a stringstream to fprintf?

UPDATE : Can I wrap the `stringstream` to a `FILE` and unwrap back?

Comment: At the end of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19749019/225186 I wrote about the case of the `istringstream`, I guess something similar can be done for `ostringstream`

Answer (score 1):

You can't "pass" the ostream to fprintf. The `FILE` structure is platform dependent.

This is probably not the best way, but you can however create an evil macro:

```
#undef fprintf
#define fprintf my_fprintf
```

And you can create two my_fprintfs, one that takes `FILE*`, and another that takes `std::stringstream&` as argument.

You can avoid the macro by simply calling my_fprintf directly, but you have to modify the call site.

You can't "wrap stringstream in FILE*" portably, but there are some system specific ways. If that's what you after, then Linux for example has fopencookie() which take function pointers to read/write functions. You could then create functions that wrap std::stringstream.