# Is there a (more) reasonable way to determine the width of a terminal targeted by an ostream?

Tags: c++, terminal, file-descriptor, ofstream, idioms

I have a function which prints some text to an ostream& it receives. I would like to make it adapt to the terminal width, if the ostream targets a terminal, and otherwise default to some value.

What I do right now is the following:

1. Get an `ofstream` from the `ostream`.
2. Get a `FILE*` from the `ofstream`.
3. Get an integer file descriptor from the `FILE*`.
4. Do `ioctl(file_descriptor, TIOCGWINSZ, &my_struct_winsize);`

with steps 1 and 2 bring due to this SO answer:

[Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109449/1593077)

but they are non-portable and GCC-specific (and I'm not sure they'll work for ostreams other than cout/cerr/cin).  Can I do better than this?

Comment: I think I would involve the user. If no user spec then I think I'd check out some terminal database. In the 80's or therabouts it was, as I recall, "termcap".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's not the issue, i.e. I don't mind checking a DB - but what should I look up in that DB? Remember I only get an ostream.

Comment: how about using ncurses?

Comment: @einpoklum Correct me if I'm wrong, but my thinking was that if/when you identify the stream as a tty (_isatty in Windows, but you're in Unixland, yes?), then there is only one relevant terminal, the one identified by terminal environment variable?

Comment: @Calvin: I know ncurses exists, and IIRC it's a C library. Can you be more specific regarding what I should do with it?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I am i Unixland (although Windows can also be Unixland with some effort). I wanted to make my question more general than your assumption, but for the sake of discussion assume you're right. Still, on my system, the value of `TERM` is `xterm`. How does that help me determine the width?

Comment: @einpoklum Google ncurses terminal size give you tons of example. If you have trouble using ncurses you may as well edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting terminal width in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)

Comment: @ThomasDickey: No, that question is about C, I'm asking about C++, note the tags.

Comment: Any C++ application can (and usually *does*) call libraries written in C.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: It's still not what I asked. Saying "do it like you would in C" is just one answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of that is gcc-specific.  For the rest, `TIOCGWINSZ` is widely implemented and used with POSIX termios ([terminal I/O](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11)), although it and the corresponding `SIGWINCH` are oddly enough not in POSIX.  Other methods of getting terminal width (still for POSIX platforms, not generally applicable to Windows):

- testing environment variables `COLUMNS` and `LINES` (many terminal applications, including those using curses do this, e.g., see [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env), provided by any [X/Open curses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/use_env.html) implementation such as [`ncurses`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html)).
- using ECMA-48 cursor position report as done by the [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program.

For Windows, none of that applies.  You would get the information from one of the Console API calls such as [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Cygwin is a special case, because it runs (more or less) POSIX-like applications which work with the `ioctl` as well as POSIX terminal I/O.  MinGW is lower-level, and does not provide any real extension to the Console API in this area.

Further reading:

- [get TIOCGWINSZ from `<sys/ioctl.h>`](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-patches/2006-q4/msg00028.html) (clarification on Cygwin mailing list)
- [signal.h - signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) (POSIX: noting absence of `SIGWINCH`)
- [ECMA-48, 
  Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)
- [Microsoft Console Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: There's also ncurses and many other higher level libraries (probably SDL too).