# How to get file descriptor from ofstream

Tags: c++, file, descriptor, fsync

I need to call fsync() to secure my data. Can you please help me to get file descriptor from ofstream.

```
string tmpconfig("config.tmp");
ofstream tcfg(tmpconfig.c_str());
if(tcfg)
{
tcfgNV.compactPrint(tcfg);
tcfg.flush();
if(!tcfg.good())
{
    tcfg.close();
    ::remove(tmpconfig.c_str());
    cout << "Failed to write the main configuration file: " << topconfig << endl;
    return false;
}
REPORT_INFO("Syncing the file: " << topconfig);
// TODO I need to call fsync() here to secure my data.
//tcfg.pubsync();
tcfg.close();
}
```

Comment: There's no portable way to get a native handle to the underlying file. There might be non-standard extension of the implementation, but without knowing which compiler and standard library implementation you use it's impossible to say.

Comment: Also, the "need" to use `fsync` is often a red herring, and the real problem is something else with other portable solutions.

Comment: The stdlib exists in many cases to abstract away platform-dependent hackery, so of course the Standard file stream doesn't expose that implementation detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a FILE\* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

Comment: Is it ok to use;  tcfg.rdbuf()->pubsync();

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C++ 2026, we have a way to retrieve the system file handle with:

```
native_handle_type handle(tcfg.native_handle());
```

More about [native_handle()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/native_handle).

On Linux and other Unices, you are likely to get a `FILE *` pointer. So in your case, you are able to do:

```
fsync(fileno(tcfg.native_handle()));
```