# Can std::ifstream get a file's unique identification

Tags: c++, ifstream, stat

We can use `stat` to get a inode number, which can **uniquely identify** the object on the system. 
code is :

```
int ret = stat(file_name, &file_info);
if (ret != 0) {
   //report error
}
std::cout << file_info.st_ino; inode numb
std::cout = file_info.st_dev;
std::cout = file_info.st_mtime;
```

So we can check is the file has been **moved or renamed**. There is another function `fstat`  which take int `fd`, not the filename. Use the filename is not a good solution because the file may be moved after we check it. For example:

```
stat(file_name)
the inode num is same as before. so the file has not been moved.
-- the file has be moved, but we can not known--//
we open the file
we process new file use old file info

fstat(fd)
the inode num is same as before. so the file has not been moved.
-- the file has be moved
ok. we process the old file  use old file info.
```

Thing goes well, until when I use c++ `ifstream`, how can do? 
Get a `fd` for `ifstream`?? or use struct `file *file` ?

Can everyone help me?

Comment: hi jamek, do we have to use fd and fstat to get a unique identification
(etc.. inode id)?  is there other function to get it from istream directly?

Comment: Short answer:  no.   The C++ standard does not specify how iostreams are implemented.  inode numbers are an implementation detail on SOME systems, but not others.

Comment: Did you read? No, there isn't. You have to do it on your own, later if you want to find a file by inode use ftw or similar function - it's depend on your os. https://stackoverflow.com/a/109522/2493292