# Creating an ofstream for a `FILE*` - possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, file-descriptor, ofstream

In C++11, is it possible to create an `std::fstream` corresponding to a `FILE*` C-standard-library file descriptor?

This would be the opposite of [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109449/1593077) .

and I'm specifically interested in an an `std::ofstream`, for writing to the file.

Comment: The short answer is "no".   `std::fstream` is not required to be implemented with any knowledge of C I/O, or to use C I/O behind the scenes.

Comment: Well, the `FILE` struct is _implementation defined_. If yours has an fd, you can create a streambuf from that.

Comment: There's the `fileno()` to get the fd. It won't help.

Comment: @rustyx Ooops, seems I confused that with a proprietary streambuf implementation we once had for that. You're right, there's no way from an fd.

Comment: It's sort of possible, but not out of the box.  At one time, I've written a custom `FILE*` holding `struct nonstd::file_stream : std::ofstream` that would use the `FILE*` passed to the file_stream constructor to use (not to own / manage / destruct).  I probably still have the code somewhere, but it's been about 20 years so I have no idea where its stowed away.  On a ZIP disk somewhere (the old SCSI connected ZIP drives).