# Getting FILE* in a safe C++ way

Tags: c++, c++17, file-handling

Is there a way to obtain the `FILE*` handle of an opened file in a modern C++ way?.. I want to avoid using `std::fopen` from `<cstdlib>` as I've been warned that it's potentially unsafe.

I tried checking if there's a way to retrieve `FILE*` from `fstream` but it seems there isn't a way to do that.

Comment: The C++ way doesn't involve FILE* at all.

Comment: So there is no way to get FILE* in C++?.. Cause there are still come functions and even boost libraries that take advantage of it

Comment: I'd be curious about what functions you're referring to, and whether the boost libraries you're referring to have been superseded by something in the Standard Library. You can naturally still use FILE*, but you're going to be bringing in those C headers to do it.

Comment: `FILE*` is from C, not C++. The C++ way to deal with files is to use `std::(i|o)fstream` instead.

Comment: Re: “warned that it’s potentially unsafe” — what’s “unsafe” about it? How do C programmers deal with it being “unsafe”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to avoid using `std::fopen` from `<cstdlib>` as I've been warned that it's potentially unsafe.

There is nothing "unsafe" about `fopen()`. It is part of the C++ standard by means of the C standard.

What they probably said is that using a RAII object is best to manage the resource (the file handle), in particular if you're using exceptions in your program.

> I tried checking if there's a way to retrieve `FILE*` from `fstream` but it seems there isn't a way to do that.

Not an easy, completely portable one. See questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109449/9305398).

If you really want a `FILE*`, use the C API.

Answer (score 1):

Some fun.

```
namespace file {
  template<auto f>
  using constant = std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(f)>, f >;

  using file_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, constant<std::fclose>>;

  FILE* unwrap( file_ptr const& ptr ) { return ptr.get(); }
  template<class T> requires (!std::is_same_v< file_ptr, std::decay_t<T> >)
  T&& unwrap( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
  file_ptr wrap( FILE* ptr ) { return file_ptr(ptr); }
  template<class T> requires (!std::is_same_v< file_ptr, std::decay_t<T> >)
  T&& wrap( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }

  template<auto f>
  auto call = [](auto&&...args){ return wrap( f( unwrap(decltype(args)(args))... ) ); };
  // most FILE* operations can be rebound as follows:
  auto open = call<std::fopen>;
  auto close = call<std::fclose>;
  auto getc = call<std::fgetc>;
  auto putc = call<std::fputc>;
  // any one that works with raw buffers (like std::fread or std::fwrite) needs more work
}
```

the core of this is that a `unique_ptr<FILE, thing that calls fclose>` is a decent quality `FILE*` C++ wrapper.

Then I added some machinery that maps `fgetc` and similar functions over to ones that operate on `file::file_ptr` by wrapping/unwrapping them.

now you can do:

```
auto pFile = file::open("hello.txt", "r");
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/YPdoov).

```
auto pFile = file::open("hello.txt", "r");
auto pFileOut = file::open("world.txt", "w");
if (pFile)
{
    while(auto c = file::getc(pFile))
    {
        file::putc(c, pFileOut);
    }
}
```

a more advanced version would take the arguments from a function pointer, toss them in a tuple, map them to-from tuples of munged arguments.

So

```
char*, int
```

would map to a `std::span<char>`.

The `call` helper instead of the naive stuff above would take the munged arguments, map them to tuples of C style arguments, concatinate the tuples together, and `std::apply` the C function.  Then map the return value.

`call` with a bit of work could even have a fixed signature instead of `auto&&...`, so IDEs could give hints.